# php - How to force download of a file?

Tags: php, download, remote-server

I'm looking to add a "Download this File" function below every video on one of my sites. I need to force the user to download the file, instead of just linking to it, since that begins playing a file in the browser sometimes. The problem is, the video files are stored on a separate server.

Any way I can force the download in PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forcing to download a file using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465573/forcing-to-download-a-file-using-php)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
<?php

// Locate.
$file_name = 'file.avi';
$file_url = 'http://www.myremoteserver.com/' . $file_name;

// Configure.
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"");

// Actual download.
readfile($file_url);

// Finally, just to be sure that remaining script does not output anything.
exit;
```

I just tested it and it works for me.

Please note that for `readfile` to be able to read a remote url, you need to have your [`fopen_wrappers`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) enabled.

Comment: Just remember to go:

str_replace('"', '\\"', $file_name)

Before putting it in the header

Comment: The flaw with this is that all the video would run through his server.  If the video is on a separate server for bandwidth reasons, this solution will not be acceptable.

Comment: Point taken. From the sound of the question, though, I got the impression that he does not have access to this remote server, otherwise it would be a trivial problem. If that is the case, as far as I know this would be the only solution.

Comment: I do have access to the remote server.

Comment: This works for me but it does not tell you the file size and estimated time left, is there a header you need to specify to do this?

Also, is it possible to use the filename of the file as it was meant to be, not to re-set it?

Comment: I have same problem, and access to remote file server? How to initiate download form app server and serve file from remote, without using bandwith of an app server?

Comment: The user is still prompted to save the file.

Comment: I think using readfile will consume both sites bandwidth. the main reason someone wants to do this is to save some bandwidth

Comment: I assume the same. @pouya. The server must download the file and then the user downloads the file from the server

Comment: @Ben If you have access to the server that has the file, you could simply `readfile` from it instead of remotely, eliminating the double bandwidth issue.

Answer (score 6):

Tested download.php file is

```
function _Download($f_location, $f_name){
  $file = uniqid() . '.pdf';

  file_put_contents($file,file_get_contents($f_location));

  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($f_name));

  readfile($file);
}

_Download($_GET['file'], "file.pdf");
```

and the link to download is

```
<a href="download.php?file=http://url/file.pdf"> Descargar </a>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<?php
$FileName = '/var/ww/file.txt';
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$FileName.'"');
readfile($FileName);
```

The key is the `header()`. You need to send the header along with the download and it will force the "Save File" dialog in the user's browser.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

    $file_name = 'video.flv';
    $file_url = 'http://www.myserver.com/secretfilename.flv';
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\""); 
    echo file_get_contents($file_url);
    die;

?>
```

Comment: Please give a more detailed description of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this is the best way or not but I like that, short & simple.

If you want to **download** file when you visit **URL**, you can do like below

```html
<a href="resume.pdf" download></a>
<script>document.querySelector('a').click();</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>download</title>
</head>

<body>
        <a href="download.php?file=ID_do_arquivo"> download </a>
</body>
</html>
```

.htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
deny from all
```

download.php

```
$file = "pdf/teste.pdf";
 if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Although your code looks great and more than likely answers the question, please add an explanation of how it works so that people can understand why it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$FileName = '/var/ww/file.txt';
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$FileName.'"');
readfile($FileName);
```

using this code. is it possible to save the file name to what you want. for example you have url: http://remoteserver.com/file.mp3 instead of "file.mp3" can you use this script to download the file as "newname.mp3"