# Make user download pdf instead of saving to a location

Tags: php, html, pdf, pdf-generation

I was trying out the following code which actually saves the pdf file to C:/xampp/
I want to create a link so that when the user clicks on it. It prompts it to save the pdf file.

```
<?php  
// create handle for new PDF document  
$pdf = pdf_new();  

// open a file  
pdf_open_file($pdf, "try1.pdf");  

// start a new page (A4)  
pdf_begin_page($pdf, 595, 842);  
pdf_set_parameter($pdf, 'FontOutline',

'Arial=c:\windows\fonts\arial.ttf');
// get and use a font object  
$font = pdf_findfont($pdf, "Arial", "host", 1); 

pdf_setfont($pdf, $font, 10);  

// print text  
pdf_show_xy($pdf, "There are more things in heaven and earth, Horatio,", 50, 750); 
pdf_show_xy($pdf, "than are dreamt of in your philosophy", 50, 730);  

// add an image under the text  
//$image = pdf_open_image_file($pdf, "jpeg", "shakespeare.jpg"); pdf_place_image($pdf, $image, 50, 650, 0.25);  

// end page  
pdf_end_page($pdf);  

// close and save file  
pdf_close($pdf);  
?>
```

Comment: Extremely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465573/forcing-to-download-a-file-using-php

Comment: @deceze.Thanks! Next time i'll make use of Search :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question and title don't quite seem to match, but you might be looking for the [`Content-Disposition`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt) header. When you send that header with a resource like a PDF, you're recommending to the browser what to do with the resource — save it to a file or render it inline (e.g., in a window).

For instance, to suggest that the browser offer to save the file locally:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=foo.pdf
```

whereas to suggest it should try to render the content inline:

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=foo.pdf
```

The browser can still do whatever it wants, but major browsers take the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `pdf_close()` use [`pdf_get_buffer()` and `pdf_delete()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdf.examples-basic.php).