# How can I make Safari download a CSV instead of showing it in the browser?

Tags: java, csv, safari, liferay

In Safari, my CSV files are being shown in the browser instead of downloading them using the Save As window.

I tried: `response.setContentType("text/csv; charset=UTF-8");`. The other browsers are fine with the second option, but Safari kept displaying the file in-browser instead of prompting the user to save it.

By the way, i'm running Liferay.

I fixed it by including this: response.setContentType("application/csv; charset=UTF-8");

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having this problem too. Where did you put the "response.setContentType("application/csv; charset=UTF-8");"?

Comment: @Sam - Have you solve above issue . I am suffering from same issue . Please help.

Answer (score 2):

`text/csv` would be the most appropriate for the content type. You also want to set the content-disposition like this:

```
response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename );
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll need to [set the `Content-Disposition` HTTP header as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802510/force-to-open-save-as-popup-open-at-text-link-click-for-pdf-in-html).

The HTTP header should look like this:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=WHATEVER_FILENAME_YOU_WANT
```

Does the `response` object have a `setContentDisposition` method too?