# SAVE AS option in IE for text file

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have links with txt file path on the page. when user clicks on it using IE then IE opens text file in IE itself rather than giving an option for save text file.

I want a "SAVE AS" option in IE when user clicks on the txt file link. Users are using any version from IE 8 to 11.

Comment: can you show the code so that we ca see what it is that you are doing incorrectly..?

Comment: you need to show your code for starters then look to see if you have something like the following 
`Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=SomeTextFile.txt");`

Comment: There is no code, those are just anchor links with text file path in href attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As I still have no reputation to comment, I suggest to add download to the  tag.

Like:

```
<a href="..." download></a>
```

Based on this thread: [Force to open “Save As…” popup open at text link click for pdf in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802510/force-to-open-save-as-popup-open-at-text-link-click-for-pdf-in-html)

Comment: Internet Explorer *does not* support the download attribute.