# File Explorer code - without force download option

Tags: php, file, browser, download

I'm looking to add a force download function to the file exploere script below. I need to force the user to download the file when he click on the $namehref, instead of opening the file in the broswer.
How do i add that to the code?

```
        <?php





        // Adds pretty filesizes
        function pretty_filesize($file) {
            $size = filesize($file);
            if ($size < 1024) {
                $size = $size . " Bytes";
            } elseif (($size < 1048576) && ($size > 1023)) {
                $size = round($size / 1024, 1) . " KB";
            } elseif (($size < 1073741824) && ($size > 1048575)) {
                $size = round($size / 1048576, 1) . " MB";
            } else {
                $size = round($size / 1073741824, 1) . " GB";
            }
            return $size;
        }

        date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Rome");

        // Checks to see if veiwing hidden files is enabled
        /*
          if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == "hidden") {
            $hide = "";
            $ahref = "./";
            $atext = "Hide";
          } else {

            $hide = ".";
            $ahref = "./?hidden";
            $atext = "Show";
          }
         */

        $hide = ".";

        if (!isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) || $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == "" || substr($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],0,2) == ".." || strstr($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], "..")) {
            $currdir = ".";
        } else {
            $currdir = urldecode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
        }

        if ($currdir == ".") 
            $label = "Root";
        else {
            $path = explode('/', $currdir);
            $label = $path[count($path)-1]; 
        }

        ?>
        <!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
           <meta charset="UTF-8">
           <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico">
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="favicon.ico">
           <title>DPP</title>


           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
           <script src="sorttable.js"></script>
        </head>

        <body>
        <div id="container" style="margin-top:-50px">
        <table class="sortable">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th bgcolor="#003399">Filename</th>
                    <th bgcolor="#003399">Type</th>

                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody><?php
        error_reporting(0);
        // Opens directory
        $myDirectory = opendir($currdir);

        // Set Forbidden Files
        $forbiddenExts = array("php", "ico", "html", "LCK", "js", "css");

        // Gets Each Entry
        while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) { 
        $exts = explode(".", $entryName); 
          if(!in_array($exts[1],$forbiddenExts)) { 
            $dirArray[] = $entryName;
          }
        }

        // Closes directory
        closedir($myDirectory);

        // Counts elements in array
        $indexCount = count($dirArray);

        // Sorts files
        //sort($dirArray);

        // Loops through the array of files
        for ($index = 0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {

            // Decides if hidden files should be displayed, based on query above.
            if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != $hide || ($currdir != '.' && $dirArray[$index] == "..")) {

                // Resets Variables
                $favicon = "";
                $class = "file";

                // Gets File Names
                $name = $dirArray[$index];
                $namehref = ($currdir == "." ? "" : $currdir . '/') . $dirArray[$index];
            $fullname = $currdir . '/' . $dirArray[$index];

                // Gets Date Modified
                $modtime = date("M j Y g:i A", filemtime($fullname));
                $timekey = date("YmdHis", filemtime($fullname));


                // Separates directories, and performs operations on those directories
                if (is_dir($currdir . '/' . $dirArray[$index])) {
                    $extn = "&lt;Folder&gt;";
                    $size = "&lt;Folder&gt;";
                    $sizekey = "0";
                    $class = "dir";

                    // Gets favicon.ico, and displays it, only if it exists.
                    if (file_exists("$namehref/favicon.ico")) {
                        $favicon = " style='background-image:url($namehref/favicon.ico);'";
                        $extn = "&lt;Website&gt;";
                    }

                    // Cleans up . and .. directories
                    if ($name == ".") {
                        $name = ". (Current Directory)";
                        $extn = "&lt;System Dir&gt;";
                        $favicon = " style='background-image:url($namehref/.favicon.ico);'";
                    }
                    if ($name == "..") {
                        $name = ".. (Return to Parent Folder)";
                        $extn = "&lt;System Dir&gt;";
                    }
                    if ($currdir == "." && $dirArray[$index] == "..")
                        $namehref = "";
                    elseif ($dirArray[$index] == "..") {
                        $dirs = explode('/', $currdir);
                        unset($dirs[count($dirs) - 1]);
                        $prevdir = implode('/', $dirs);
                        $namehref = '?' . $prevdir;
                    }
                    else
                        $namehref = '?' . $namehref;
                }

                // File-only operations
                else {
                    // Gets file extension
                    $extn = pathinfo($dirArray[$index], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                    // Prettifies file type
                    switch ($extn) {
                        case "png": $extn = "PNG Image";
                            break;
                        case "jpg": $extn = "JPEG Image";
                            break;
                        case "ppsx": $extn = "Microsoft Power Point";
                            break;
                        case "jpeg": $extn = "JPEG Image";
                            break;
                        case "svg": $extn = "SVG Image";
                            break;
                        case "gif": $extn = "GIF Image";
                            break;
                        case "ico": $extn = "Windows Icon";
                            break;

                        case "txt": $extn = "Text File";
                            break;
                        case "log": $extn = "Log File";
                            break;
                        case "htm": $extn = "HTML File";
                            break;
                        case "html": $extn = "HTML File";
                            break;
                        case "xhtml": $extn = "HTML File";
                            break;
                        case "shtml": $extn = "HTML File";
                            break;
                        case "ppt": $extn = "Microsoft Power Point";
                            break;
                        case "js": $extn = "Javascript File";
                            break;
                        case "css": $extn = "Stylesheet";
                            break;

                        case "pdf": $extn = "PDF Document";
                            break;
                        case "xls": $extn = "Spreadsheet";
                            break;
                        case "xlsx": $extn = "Spreadsheet";
                            break;
                        case "doc": $extn = "Microsoft Word Document";
                            break;
                        case "docx": $extn = "Microsoft Word Document";
                            break;

                        case "zip": $extn = "ZIP Archive";
                            break;
                        case "htaccess": $extn = "Apache Config File";
                            break;
                        case "exe": $extn = "Windows Executable";
                            break;

                        default: if ($extn != "") {
                                $extn = strtoupper($extn) . " File";
                            } else {
                                $extn = "Sconosciuto";
                            } break;
                    }

                    // Gets and cleans up file size
                    $size = pretty_filesize($fullname);
                    $sizekey = filesize($fullname);
                }

                // Output
                echo("
                <tr class='$class'>
                    <td><a href='$namehref'$favicon class='name'>$name</a></td>
                    <td><a href='$namehref'>$extn</a></td>

                </tr>");
               }
            }
        ?>

                </tbody>
            </table>


        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force file download with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php)

Comment: `error_reporting(0);` Always a danger sign. Not going anywhere near this for less that $100 an hour

Comment: This is different @ Al Foиce ѫ

Comment: as for PHP force download, `header` modification would work *BUT* you're actually looking for HTML force user download, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802510/force-to-open-save-as-popup-open-at-text-link-click-for-pdf-in-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');   // file type 
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" .$filename . "\"");
    header("Cache-control: private");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

Answer (score 0):

use this line:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename={FILE_NAME}");
```

since it modifies header information, it should be placed above all `echo`s

Comment: at the beginning of the php script that grabs the file

Comment: Oh I understand now, you're question is very confusing. You'll have to make a new PHP page that handles that, look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802510/force-to-open-save-as-popup-open-at-text-link-click-for-pdf-in-html