# How do you include an asset download link in markdown?

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I have a small JavaScript file in assets that I'd like to link to as a direct download.

The following link simply opens the file in the current tab:

```
[myFile.js]({{file name='myFile.js'}})
```

I'd like the file to actually download on clicking the link. Is that at all possible in markdown?

Comment: Markdown just generates HTML, so this is you answer: [Force to open “Save As…” popup open at text link click for pdf in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3802510/866026) or [href image link download on click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2408146/866026). Just include the raw HTML in your Markdown.

Comment: Some wiki hosts (e.g. GitHub wiki) strip out the 'download' attribute from your <a> tag. Sometimes you can work around that by zipping the file and providing a markdown link to the zipped file. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46938081/456550) for more info.

Answer (score 10):

It's the same as a link. `[File Name](url)`. It works for me on Github pages' Jekyll implementation of markdown.

Answer (score 7):

Try using inline HTML
`<a href="myFile.js" download>Click to Download</a>`

Answer (score 6):

**On GitHub.com**

The GitHub wiki site strips out the download attribute, so conventional approaches as mentioned before aren't going to work properly.  However, I found the following will work:

```
<a id="raw-url" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github-username/project/master/filename">Download FILE</a>
```

Replace 'github-username' with your git hub user name, obviously.  Replace 'project' with project name, 'filename' with the actual file name.  This also assumes the file is not in a sub folder.  Also, notice, it is actually hosted on raw.githubusercontent.com.

However, due the difficulty, I'm almost wondering if the site was intentionally deterring such behavior.

Comment: You can also use relative links too, if you're in a README or something.

Comment: It does not seem to work, neither with absolute nor with relative links. It just open a new tab with raw file contents.

Comment: @Kuba I haven't checked recently, but I wouldn't be surprised if GitHub changed the functionality on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Incase of using [remarkable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/remarkable) markdown parser, you can use [remarkable-seo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/remarkable-seo) package to define download attribute in markdown.

Sample Markdown:

```
[Download Minion](https://octodex.github.com/images/minion.png "download")
```

Output:

```html
<a href="https://octodex.github.com/images/minion.png" title="Download" download>Download</a>
```

Leaving this as an answer over here so might help someone else.