# Can I link to a file for downloading (other than PDF) in a GitHub wiki?

Tags: github, hyperlink, wiki

When you link to a PDF file using:

`[download this](file.pdf)`

it downloads the pdf file. I have an excel workbook that I'd like to allow someone to download using:

`[download this](file.xlsx)`

When I click it, it takes me to create a new page in the wiki. Is there any markdown syntax I can add that identifies the link as something to download?

If I have to, I can save the excel workbook as a PDF, but it's not going to be pretty.

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using an Excel spreadsheet (which requires downloading and an installation of Excel to use) rather than just a link to a shared Google spreadsheet?

Comment: Primarily, it's because this repository will also act as an archive for the next 5-10 years, and I was wanting everything in the same place. That is a good idea, though. Based on your response, I'm assuming what I'm looking for isn't possible, so I'll either use your suggestion or PDF it. Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't assume it isn't possible (if I knew that for certain, I would have posted an answer). I just wondered about using a format that requires people to have Excel installed and download a file when there was another more universal option available that didn't require either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, try making a `files` subdirectory in your wiki, and putting your files in there.

I tried using an html anchor tag

```
<a href="files/file.csv" download="file.csv">download this</a>
```

instead of the markdown link syntax

```
[download this](files/file.csv)
```

but it seems that GitHub wiki strips out the download attribute from the anchor tag.

In the end, I zipped my spreadsheet in a zip file and had the markdown link point to the zip file.

```
[download this](files/file.csv.zip)
```