# Instruct browser to make user select location for downloaded file?

Tags: html, http-headers

Some browsers has the option to automatically save downloaded files to a folder, without prompting the user where to save the file. This has posed a problem for us where the user automatically saves the file in "Downloads" instead of selecting a proper location.

Is there any HTML-attribute, HTTP-header or JavaScript solution to instruct browsers to prompt for save location for downloaded files even though they are configured otherwise?

**Note:** I am well aware that this is probably not possible, but wanted to see if someone hopefully can prove me wrong.

**Related issues:**

- How to make browser download link target instead of navigate: [Force to open "Save As..." popup open at text link click for pdf in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802510/force-to-open-save-as-popup-open-at-text-link-click-for-pdf-in-html)

Comment: I'd be interested in what "a proper location" is in your use case…

Comment: @deceze In our use case it is on the USB-stick that the user has connected to their computer. The case in brief is to transfer the data offline from one device to another, and a common mistake the user does is that they think they are done when the download the file even though it automatically saves to default location.

Comment: @deceze Worth mentioning is that it is quite an odd case and I would not recommend forcing the user (if it was possible) to choose location normally.

Comment: @deceze cloudconvert is an example of a website that does that (if you need an example you can add it in the question), so it ***is*** possible, but i've been searching for a long time on the internet and i still don't know how to do it

Comment: @Konstei I've tried Cloudconvert and I don't see where it lets me choose a download location, so I have no idea what you mean…

Comment: @deceze i just tried it, it seems that if you go to cloudconvert and try to convert something it just converts and you download it from the download button, but i tried converting a file just before writing the comment and i got a preview and download popup with another download button that let me choose where to save it (for reproduction i searched for "mp4 to mp3" -> cloud convert -> selected a file and convert -> preview popup when finished with the special download/save button)

Comment: @deceze i found out you can toggle the browser setting to always get prompted before any file download, but i had that off. The reason i got prompted might have been because i was not logged into any google chrome account, so it just prompted; idk how it works but everybody says that you (as the dev) cannot force that prompt, so that was probably it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It's a browser preference. If the user prefers not to be bothered by their browser for download locations, then that's their prerogative. They'll deal with the file location *after* it has been downloaded. A server cannot influence that behaviour.

Comment: Marking you as the correct answer unless someone proves us wrong.