# download created pdf by navigating to a location in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter, pdf

I have created a pdf file of a page using `DOMpdf` as following.

```
<?php

use Dompdf\Dompdf;
class Pdfgenerator {

  public function generate($html, $filename='', $stream=TRUE, $paper = 'A4', $orientation = "portrait")
  {
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF(array('enable_remote' => true));
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
    $dompdf->setPaper($paper, $orientation);
    $dompdf->render();
    if ($stream) {
        $dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));
    } else {
        return $dompdf->output();
    }
  }
}
```

On clicking `Save As Pdf` button on a view page, pdf of the page is created in a controller function using `DOMpdf` and open the pdf in new tab in browser from where it can be downloaded on the download path which is set for browser.

```
$html = $this->load->view('test/pdfview', $this->data, true);
$this->load->library('pdfgenerator');
$filename = 'testfile';
$this->pdfgenerator->generate($html, $filename, true, 'a4', '');
```

What I actually want is to download the file on given path such that when a PDF is created a save prompt will open which already navigates to given location. If its the right location  I can press save, if not I can navigate to the proper save location. 
These are somewhat similar questions already asked which I found but I couldnt find them helpful.

- [Force to open “Save As…” popup open at text link click for pdf in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802510/force-to-open-save-as-popup-open-at-text-link-click-for-pdf-in-html)
- [JavaScript: Create and save file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a script like below in php which will send generated pdf to the browser

```
 <?php


use Dompdf\Dompdf;
class Pdfgenerator {

  public function downLoadPdf(){
        $name= "testfile.pdf";

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($name) . "\";");
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($name));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile("your_file_path/".$name); //showing the path to the server where the file is to be download

    }
}
    ?>
```

Just add this function in your class and call  it using ajax on click of save button (If it exists in your view page)
When you call this script from browser on clicking save button,Browser will automatically open save window and you can save the file at your desired location

Comment: this doesnt seem to work . I added this code after creating pdf . i.e after `$this->pdfgenerator->generate($html, $filename, true, 'a4', '')` , the problem is same , the pdf opens in browser page and no save window appears.

Comment: I have edited the answer.You should create a new function and call it on save button from your view.

Comment: I appreciate your help but I fail to understand how pdf will be generated with your snippet, i.e, on save button call, the function which convert html to pdf is called ( i.e. `$this->pdfgenerator->generate($html, $filename, true, 'a4', '')`) , if i call downloadPdf on save, `testfile.pdf` wont be even created yet to download ??

Comment: You have to save pdf somewhere when you call ``generate`` function. The snippet I have added in answer wil not generate pdf, It will send the saved pdf from your server location to browser. Your function is just generating the pdf file and displaying it in the browser.You have to save it somewhere in your server for downloading purpose.Hope you get my point

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Codeigniter 4.2.6

    public function saveAsPdf($emp_code="00000")
    {
        $dompdf = new Dompdf();
        $data = [
            'imageSrc'    => "#",
            'name'         => 'John Doe',
            'address'      => 'USA',
            'mobileNumber' => '000000000',
            'email'        => 'john.doe@email.com'
        ];
        $html = view('resume', $data);
        $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
        $dompdf->render();
        // $dompdf->stream('resume.pdf');
        $output = $dompdf->output();
        $flname = $emp_code.".pdf";
        file_put_contents(WRITEPATH . 'uploads/employee/'.$flname, $output);

        $insdata     = array(
            'emp_code' => $in_title??202222,                             
            'file_name' => $flname,                             
            'status' => 1,                        
            'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')                
        );

        $database = \Config\Database::connect();
        $db = $database->table('emp_payslip');
        $save = $db->insert($insdata);
        
    }
```