# How to download PDF file using URL in angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, download

How to download a PDF file using file URL. I am tried many eg, but no luck. All are opening the file in the new tab. anyone have any idea about this.

Eg code

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = file_path;
link.download = file_path.substr(file_path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
link.click();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802510/force-to-open-save-as-popup-open-at-text-link-click-for-pdf-in-html

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [download attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) like so:

```
<a href="file link" download target="_blank">Click here to download</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can i use: https://caniuse.com/#search=download

HTML5 over link add attribute download like this example:

```
<a href="assets/pdfs/MYFILETODOWNLOAD.pdf" download>
THE PDF DOWNLOAD IT !
</a>
```