# Download PDF when it's a url

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

Hey I have an issue where I'm trying to create a button where it automatically downloads a pdf. I saw many examples where it does works by a filepath (root/folder/pdf) but not by url.

Trying this because I'm using wordpress guttenberg and want less technical people to be able to upload a pdf url.

pdf url - https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf

```
<a class="btn"  href="<?php echo the_field('pdf_url') ?>" download ><span>Download PDF</span></a>
```

Outputs as

```
<a class="btn" href="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf" download><span>Download PDF</span></a>
```

Comment: What's the extra word `download` doing after the URL?

Comment: @Dave it suppose to download the file instead of link you to that https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: Can you explain how the given html is not what you want? can you share the "btn" css if you are expecting this to behave as a button?

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802510/force-to-open-save-as-popup-open-at-text-link-click-for-pdf-in-html

Comment: Its just a styling class. 

Right now when clicking the button it just takes you to the pdf. But I want when clicked to download the pdf instead of opening the link.

Comment: The link @FelippeDuarte posted may be helpful. What browser are you trying this in?

Comment: Is the file on the same server? copy from w3schools: * Chrome 65+ and Firefox only support same-origin download links.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "_target" attribute to download the PDF in new tab.

```
<a class="btn" href="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf" target="_blank" download><span>Download PDF</span></a>
```

If the PDF is still not downloading and is being opened in a new tab, change the browser settings. Visit this blog to see how to change the browser settings: [How to change browser download settings for PDF files](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001114.htm)

Comment: target="_blank" is maybe a good fallback option but not necessary in most cases