# Apex - How to download pdf file instead of showing it in the browser?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm running Apex 19.2.

I have a pdf stored as blob file in a table. I'm trying to download the blob in a page process.

The process works fine however, the file doesn't download but gets displayed in the browser instead.

Can anyone help please ? I need the file to download and not show in the browser...

Here is my code :

```
        File Blob; -- Blob content is set somewhere else...
        sys.HTP.init;
        sys.OWA_UTIL.mime_header(MimeType, FALSE);
        sys.HTP.p('Content-Length: ' || DBMS_LOB.getlength(File));
        sys.HTP.p('Content-Disposition: filename="report.pdf"');
        sys.OWA_UTIL.http_header_close;

        sys.WPG_DOCLOAD.download_file(file);
        apex_application.stop_apex_engine;
```

Thanks,
Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
sys.HTP.p('Content-Disposition: filename="report.pdf"');
```

To this:

```
sys.HTP.p('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="report.pdf"');
```

Answer (score 0):

By default this is an individual browser setting, a preference configurable by end users.

- https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/download-pdf-files-chrome/
- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/all/how-to-change-microsoft-edge-to-download-pdf-files/b24dc4b7-14b5-4fe4-85ac-71e28953635e
- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/985483

It does appear that it can be forced through the link/URL that generates the PDF:

- [Force to open "Save As..." popup open at text link click for PDF in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802510/force-to-open-save-as-popup-open-at-text-link-click-for-pdf-in-html)