# How can I set the file name for a download link?

Tags: html

I would like to download an HTML file, let's say test1.pdf. Here's what I have right now:

```html
<a href="https://-----/test1.pdf" download>download </a>
```

How can I make it so that it can download as test2.pdf?

Comment: Is that just a static file or do you have some server logic behind it? You can give alternate download filenames with a Content-Disposition header, but probably not just configuring it in HTML.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802510/force-to-open-save-as-popup-open-at-text-link-click-for-pdf-in-html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force to open "Save As..." popup open at text link click for PDF in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802510/force-to-open-save-as-popup-open-at-text-link-click-for-pdf-in-html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create download link in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793751/how-can-i-create-download-link-in-html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can suggest a filename for the browser to use when saving the file in the value of the `download` attribute.

```html
<a href="https://-----/test1.pdf" download="test2.pdf">download </a>
```

Comment: This is not working in Chrome browser 112.0

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. The download load attribute specify its a download and not a link.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download="w3logo">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="https://-----/test1.pdf" download="test2.pdf">download </a>
```

That's all you have to do.