# How do I force a link to download a document not preview it

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I am generating a table of entries in a MySQL database using PHP. Each record references a document. I am putting a button link in the table to download the document for that record. The documents largely link to csv files. However, when clicking on them, it loads the csv file in the browser, but I want to force it to download the file when the button is clicked.

```
<a href="../../uploads/03/12/Y2 PTM 01 Sept 2019.csv" class="btn btn-sm btn-teal"><i class="fas fa-download mg-r-10"></i>Download</a>
```

Is there a way to make the button download the document and not load it in the browser? The files will always be .csv or .xlsx files.

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802510/force-to-open-save-as-popup-open-at-text-link-click-for-pdf-in-html) answer your question?

Comment: Brilliant - ta. I found an answer which works from that page.  download target=\"_blank\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Joroen's comment, in the linked page, there is something which says to use:

a href="link name" download target="_blank"

Which seems to work - in chrome at least.

Comment: Both anchor attributes (`download` and `target`) are now widely supported by all major browsers. The post I linked to is from over 10 years ago!