# How can I force the download/open dialog box to show for a PDF from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, mime-types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery: how to force a pdf download automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598658/jquery-how-to-force-a-pdf-download-automatically)

Afternoon folks,

I have a **pdf file** which the user can **download**. I want this to be done from **Javascript** rather than an `<a>` or similar.

So I have this code, but it opens in a new window/tab.

```
  window.open(url,'Download');
```

How can I tell the browser to show a download dialog box, instead of displaying the PDF inline?

Comment: Don't do this; it is user-unfriendly. If I told my browser to open PDF files instead of download them, that's what I want!! No website should try to override it.

Comment: @Domenic - it is a link to download the pdf though. If I click a link to download something I dont want it opened for me!

Comment: If I click on a link to a PDF on the web, I always want to view the PDF, never to download it. That's why I set up my browser that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server has to serve up the document with a "Content-disposition" header:

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename="yourfile.pdf";
```

You can't make that happen from JavaScript.

Comment: Yes its straight forward if I set it server side, sadly I want to do it client side

Comment: Well I don't think there's any way to force that.  That is, I don't know of any way to tell a browser to perform an HTTP operation while also forcing it to behave as if the server did send back a "Content-disposition" like that.

Comment: No same. I didn't know if there was a way to pass the mime type to `window.open`.

Comment: I modified it to work like this in the end.