# set onclick in codebehind for Anchor tag to download pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am trying to use anchor in codebehind and download a pdf when that anchor is clicked. I have downloading stuff working fine on pageload, but i am not sure how to set onlick to download for pdf.

```
HtmlAnchor apdf = new HtmlAnchor();
apdf.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
apdf.InnerText = dsreport.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ImageName"].ToString();
apdf.Attributes.Add("style", "font-weight: bold; font-size: 13px; margin: 0px;font-family: Arial; color: #1e7c9b; text-decoration: underline");
apdf.Attributes.Add("onclick", "");
```

for each onclick, i have to set the below code, so the pdf gets download only on click.

```
byte[] aByteArrayOfTheFile = (byte[])(dsreport.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ImageData"]);
SendAsFileToBrowser(aByteArrayOfTheFile, "application/pdf", "downloaded.pdf");
```

**UPDATE :**

```
 public static string SendAsFileToBrowser(byte[] File, string Type, string FileName)
 {
    string disp = "attachment";
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileName))
    {
        disp = "inline";
    }

    // set headers
    //char r = HttpContext.Current.Response;

    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = Type; // eg "image/Png"
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", File.Length.ToString());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", disp + "; filename=" + FileName + "; size=" + File.Length.ToString());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();       

    // write data to requesting browser
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(File);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    return "";
}
```

using this opens on pageload, not on Onclick. Want to download only when the user clicks.

I am using c# 2.0 in VS 2005 and sql server 2005. setting onclick in code behind is really a mess in my head. Thank you in advance for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

try this if you want for the pdf to be viewable in a browser

apdf.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.location.href='../linktopdf/thepdf.pdf;'");

if you want to download the pdf, you can create an ashx web service with content type response set to application/pdf as a response and download it from there as byes. The download window should then appear.

here is a link to a helpful thread:

[How to force a pdf download automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598658/jquery-how-to-force-a-pdf-download-automatically)

Answer (score 0):

Oh I see what you need now. Try this:

```
    apdf.Click += new EventHandler(this.SendAsFileToBrowser);   

    container.Controls.Add(apdf);
```

And make sure to place this code in the Pre_Init method of the page NOT the Page_load.

Try this and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I have HTMLAnchor code on an OnClick event of a button. So whenever i clicked the button it is downloading pdf, but instead i want  to show the link and only when the link is clicked, the pdf should be opened. I hope i am clear Kevin. Thanks for your time.