# How to force browser to download, not view, PDF documents in ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

just want to ask how can I prevent the web Browser from View on Browser because every time user click the link to download it View in Browser

```
asp.net controller 
<li><asp:HyperLink ID="hl_download" runat="server" >Download</asp:HyperLink></li>
html
<a id="dnn_ctr932_View_hl_download" href="/ideaPark/DesktopModules/ResourceModule/pdf_resources/IdeaPark_ER_diagram.pdf">Download</a>
```

Comment: this is a user setting. don't mess with the user. If I used your site and I didn't get the expected behaviour I would be annoyed.

Comment: I know that but our client request that

Comment: you fake the pdf download as a download instead of a pdf document by sending a header `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`, here's how you do it in php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php

Comment: that's PHP my problem is in .net

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force a pdf download automatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598658/how-to-force-a-pdf-download-automatically)

Comment: A good example: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/afenster/how-to-download-a-file-in-asp-net/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use a linkbutton so you can run serverside code on click:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="hl_download" runat="server" OnClick="hl_download_Click">Download</asp:LinkButton>
```

Then, in the codebehind:

```
public void hl_download_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding","Binary");
    Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"IdeaPark_ER_diagram.pdf\"");
    Response.WriteFile(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + @"ideaPark\DesktopModules\ResourceModule\pdf_resources\IdeaPark_ER_diagram.pdf");
    Response.End();
}
```

This assumes that the web path maps cleanly to the filesystem path of the file. Otherwise modify `Response.WriteFile()` so that it points to the location of the pdf file on the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem a few days ago and found a great solution posted by another here on StackOverflow. It's not 100% the same scenario as it uses HttpRequests to get files on another server, but sending the file to the browser in an octet-stream will guarantee a download window to pop.

[Download/Stream file from URL - asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596747/download-stream-file-from-url-asp-net)