# Download file Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have `.zip` file in file system. I want to download that file. So far I have done

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(zipName);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

But it directly opens up the file rather than saving it. How can download it instead if saving?

I have also seen `DownloadFile(String, String)`  but what will be first argument in my case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force browser to download, not view, PDF documents in ASP.NET Webforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339023/how-to-force-browser-to-download-not-view-pdf-documents-in-asp-net-webforms)

Comment: You can get **[`some help here`](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/9383/file-download-in-Asp-Net-with-C-Sharp.aspx)**

Comment: @fubo No, its not duplicate. Because my browser download excel files but not zip. So I guess browser settings is fine

Comment: try adding `<mimeMap fileExtension=".zip" mimeType="application/zip" />` to web config > syste.webserver > staticcontent

Answer (score 1):

You have to zip and than get the bytes from that zip and pass them

```
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}.{1}", fileName, fileExtension));
context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
context.Response.OutputStream.Write(zipBytesArray, 0, zipBytesArray.Length);
context.Response.End();
```

Comment: than you have to get the bytes from that zip and pass them through.

Comment: Short and simple use the following: `byte [] data = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\temp\\file.zip");`

Comment: still opening file :(

Comment: write your full snippet because this code works so it's not this

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to download it from the remote server then you can simply use the WebClient class

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(remoteFilePath, FileName);
```

or

```
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    int bufferSize = 1;

    Response.Clear();
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition:", "attachment; filename=" +filename);
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", resp.ContentLength.ToString());
    Response.ContentType = "application/download";

    byte[] ByteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize + 1];
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ByteBuffer, true);
    Stream rs = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize + 1];
    while (rs.Read(ByteBuffer, 0, ByteBuffer.Length) > 0)
    {
        Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
        Response.Flush();
    }
```

Comment: Why map path sir? it is in network not on the same server.

Comment: @Imad:- You have to download the file from a remote server?

Comment: @Imad:- You can make use of WebClient class or also check this: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/357660/Download-files-from-a-remote-server-folder-using-a