# Download sharepoint list attachment in IE browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, sharepoint, download

I want to download list attachment files in list display form mode on clicking file name hyperlink. For .doc, .docx ,.xls, .xlsx it will gives option to download in IE browser but not for .pdf, .txt and image files. I don't want files to be directly open in browser.

Is there any way to do it using javascript or Nintex forms?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question has been asked many times before, [such as here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598658/how-to-force-a-pdf-download-automatically) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802510/force-to-open-save-as-popup-open-at-text-link-click-for-pdf-in-html). Short answer is that this behavior can be controlled by the user via their IE settings, and from server side code by setting the HttpResponse header to tell the browser to download instead of stream, but you can't control this behavior from client side code. If you save the files as .zip instead of .pdf they'll download.