# I have a website where user can download pdf files automatically,its should not open in new tab

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

I have a website where user can download pdf files automatically,its should not open in new tab .Its working fine in android devices but not in Iphone and Ipad.In iphone and Ipad its opning in new tab.

below is link of pdf files

```
<a href="example.pdf">download my files</a>
```

Comment: Use StackOverflow's search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598658/how-to-force-a-pdf-download-automatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force a pdf download automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598658/how-to-force-a-pdf-download-automatically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add download in your `<a>` tag

```
 <a href="example.pdf" download>download my files</a>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46972832/i-have-a-website-where-user-can-download-pdf-files-automatically-its-should-not/46972996?noredirect=1#comment80894989_46972996

Answer (score -1):

try this property  download

for example

download my files