# How to force the user to download a file, not to view it?

Tags: php, pdf, http-headers

I have a download page where i have kept musics, pictures, ebooks and etc. Whenever users click at the image it opens it, and same things happen with .pdf files if the user has installed pdf reader on their PC?

I dont want them to open the file but to download it? Any ideas

Comment: Multiple duplicates. Search "PHP force download"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forcing to download a file using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465573/forcing-to-download-a-file-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a header to force the download.

```
header("Content-Disposition: Attachment")
header("Content-Disposition: Attachment;filename=FILENAME_HERE")
```

from http://www.symkat.com/force-download-with-http-headers

Comment: The link you posted does not work. Or is it only me who has the Problem?

Comment: Could you please include the relevant parts in your answer? Right now it's a link-only post which is not really appropriate on SO.

Answer (score 5):

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=NAME_OF_YOUR_FILE');
```

Answer (score 0):

With Apache mod_headers:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "([^/]+\.jpg)$" REQUESTED_FILE_BASENAME=$1
SetEnvIf Request_URI "([^/]+\.mp3)$" REQUESTED_FILE_BASENAME=$1
SetEnvIf Request_URI "([^/]+\.pdf)$" REQUESTED_FILE_BASENAME=$1
Header set Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=\"%{REQUESTED_FILE_BASENAME}e\"" env=REQUESTED_FILE_BASENAME
```

The instructions can be placed inside a `.htaccess` file which itself must go in the directory containing your media. You use just about any extension. The following line might also help against aggressive plugins:

```
Header set Content-Type "application/octet-stream" env=REQUESTED_FILE_BASENAME
```