# how to make a file download then user open index.html?

Tags: html

What I need is when user open, foe example, www.mydomain.com/install , he would be offered to download a file.

I made an index file in that folder with

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=myfile.sis">
```

but on some devices instead of downloading, it would attempt to open and display the file in that strange hex(?) format.

any idea... thanks!

P.S.

```
<?php
header("Location: skyeye.sis");
exit;
?>
```

does the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to send the right headers that force the browser to treat the file as a download.

You use PHP. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465573/forcing-to-download-a-file-using-php) gives one option. It would mean that you would have a PHP script be requested, and serve the SIS file.

If you use Apache, this should also be possible in a `.htaccess` file telling the web server to serve the right headers for the `.sis` file type - this would be less straining on the resources, as it is not handled by PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, looked up the header and it works!

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/sis');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sss.sis"');
readfile('sss.sis');
exit;
?>
```

Comment: You're welcome, although you may want to use `application/octet-stream` as the content type, in case the client has an application that can handle sis files (and might open the file instead of downloading it.)