# Force file download in php

Tags: php

I have built a simple file manager where users can download any type of file such as pdf, word or gif files. I want all of them to download file rather than view it in browsers. The uploaded filenames are stored in database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forcing to download a file using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465573/forcing-to-download-a-file-using-php)

Comment: This has been asked a dozen or more times on this site.

Comment: I am asking for multi format download, not just pdf. I would like th eclients to download word, excel, gif as well

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php
// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile('original.pdf');
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 5):

You can use the "Content-Disposition" header for that:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment");
```

The [PHP manual](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) provides an excellent example for that.

Answer (score 2):

Normally setting the `Content-Disposition` to `attachment` before sending a file force a download by the browser.

You either need to configure your web server to provide this header for the files or send them yourself via PHP, sending a specific header before like :

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=your_file_name.pdf');
```

Beware that the first solution is better as you won't risk your downloads being cut because the script running time is too long (you could also alter it).

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT\n");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Content-type: application/pdf;\n");
$len = filesize($filename);
header("Content-Length: $len;\n");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"downfile.pdf\";\n\n");
echo readfile($filename)
```

Comment: If you want to avoid caching, you'd better to use the `Cache-Control: no-cache` header. Those newlines (`\n`) and `;` are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

source code taken from the [TCPDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCPDF)  library

```
            // download PDF as file
            if (ob_get_contents()) {
                $this->Error('Some data has already been output, can\'t send PDF file');
            }
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            if (headers_sent()) {
                $this->Error('Some data has already been output to browser, can\'t send PDF file');
            }
            header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0'); // HTTP/1.1
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
            header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
            // force download dialog
            if (strpos(php_sapi_name(), 'cgi') === false) {
                header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream', false);
                header('Content-Type: application/download', false);
                header('Content-Type: application/pdf', false);
            } else {
                header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
            }
            // use the Content-Disposition header to supply a recommended filename
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($name).'";');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            $this->sendOutputData($this->getBuffer(), $this->bufferlen);
            break;
```

anyways the most important part is

```
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($name).'";');
```

and notice that final `;` inside the string, without it, it won't work