# Write a text file and force to download with php

Tags: php

Im using a button to direct to a script which creates a text file:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("file.txt", "w");
fwrite($handle, "text1.....");
fclose($handle);
?>
```

after that I want the web browser to propose to download or open this file
how should I do? Thanks

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force file download in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718962/force-file-download-in-php)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

use [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) and `application/octet-stream` headers

```
<?php
    $handle = fopen("file.txt", "w");
    fwrite($handle, "text1.....");
    fclose($handle);

    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename('file.txt'));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('file.txt'));
    readfile('file.txt');
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: Thx I've tried it works but if I want the web browser to propose to download 2 files how should I do?

Comment: you cannot force to download 2 files, unless you call them separately from another page ... with iframes!

Comment: It was necessary for me to change my handle: $handle = fopen("php://output", "w");  Also, it seemed that fwrite wasn't overwriting anything, so I had to call ob_end_clean()

Comment: To note that if you are using ajax (dataType: 'json') to post data and call the PHP file, the content of the text file will be returned as text regardless what you put in your PHP code.

Comment: Thnx but unable to fetch data in loop. Its showing only single data in txt file. How should I do?

Comment: @MihaiIorga I am outputting in .rtf format. Could I change my font-family?

Answer (score 6):

```
$content = file_get_contents ($filename);
header ('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
echo $content;
```

Should work

Comment: it's better to add `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename('file.txt'));` also to get proper filename