# How to export html form to csv file

Tags: javascript, php, html, csv

I am trying to create a form that a user can enter data into and then when they click submit, that data will be added as a new row to a csv file stored on the server which I can then download. I have tried both some php stuff and javascript, both of which seem to be good, but I am not very experienced in either.

Here is basicaly the html form:

```
<form name="xyz_form">
    <section class="border-bottom">
<div class="content">
    <h3>ID Number</h3>
    <div class="form-control-group">
        <div class="form-control form-control-number">
            <input type="number" id="id_number">
        </div>
    </div>
            <h3>First Name</h3>
    <div class="form-control-group">
        <div class="form-control form-control-text">
            <input type="text" id="first_name">
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--.content-->
    <section class="data-capture-buttons one-buttons">
       <div class="content">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="javascript:addToCSVFile()">
       </div>
    </section><!--.data-capture-buttons-->
```

The Javascript is in the header of the html file and it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function addToCSVFile() {
            var csvData = new Array();  // To collect the names
            var csvFilePath = "Data.csv"; // File name

            // Collect General Information
            csvData[0] = document.getElementById('id_number').value;
            csvData[1] = document.getElementById('first_name').value;

              var fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
            var oStream = fso.OpenTextFile(csvFilePath, 8, true, 0);
            oStream.WriteLine(csvData.join(','));
            oStream.Close();
            clearData();
            alert("Data Added Successfully");
     }

     function clearData() {
            document.getElementById('id_number').value = "";
            document.getElementById('first_name').value = "";
                     }
    </script>
```

And right now I have the `onClick="javascript:addToCSVFile()">` but it also doesn't work when I set the form action to the handler.php file and the mothod to post and remove the onlick. This is the php file.

```
   <?
    if(isset($_POST['match_scouting'])){
       $del = "\t";
     //Collect Info
     $data[1] = $_POST['id_number'];
     $data[2] = $_POST['first_name'];
    $file = fopen("Data.csv", "a");
    $data = "\r\n".implode($del, $data);
    fwrite($file, $data);
    fclose($file);
    echo "The data has been added successfully";
 }else{
   header("location: form.html");
 }
 ?>
```

If I am doing this wrong, could you point me in a different direction? What I am ultimately trying to do however is save the form data somehow and I thought this would be easier then setting up an SQL Database since I have never done that before.

Comment: Sidenote: Your form has no method, therefore it will default to a GET. Then you're using POST variables, which won't work unless you use `method="post"`

Answer (score 1):

For this you do not need to apply any javascript code. Just add an action to your form

```
<form name="xyz_form" action="proces.php" method="get">
```

submit will now redirect you to that php file. that php file should contain this:

```
<?php
    $keys = array('id_number','first_name');
    $csv_line = array();
    foreach($keys as $key){
        array_push($csv_line,'' . $_GET[$key]);
    }
    $fname = 'file_to_write_to.csv';
    $csv_line = implode(',',$csv_line);
    if(!file_exists($fname)){$csv_line = "\r\n" . $csv_line;}
    $fcon = fopen($fname,'a');
    $fcontent = $csv_line;
    fwrite($fcon,$csv_line);
    fclose($fcon);
?>
```

`$Keys` is all the names of the input fields you have, and you can add as many as you'd like. `$fname` is the name of the file you want to write to. The csv file gets added new lines when the form is submitted.

You could look after this: [Write a text file and force to download with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903436/write-a-text-file-and-force-to-download-with-php). If you want to force download the file. You can also look into this for a redirect instead of download: [How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php). You could also add:

```
echo file_get_contents($fname);
```

to your *PHP*

Comment: I tried that and now when I click submit the browser redirects to the php file which appears blank in the browser and a csv file is created with just a string of commas and no data. If I use the `echo file_get_contents($fname);` Then I just see the same sringof commas

Comment: The PHP script is not supposed to show anything yet, right now its just the csv file creation. And I executed this code, and it works. You must have done something wrong.

Comment: It doesn't actually add any data to the csv file, only a string of commas. It just writes an empty csv file. Do I have to do somethgin else to actually write the data the user inputs into the csv file?

Comment: If only a string of comma's is entered, you are clearly not processing everything correct. I used this script to build a CSV file. It worked, so clearly, you're doing something wrong. The comma's are being added, so the writing to the file works. Now try to find out how your PHP can acces the variables. Probably just have to check whether you are processing your AJAX request right.

Comment: You can also use the built-in functions for csv-handling, e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php