# How to export data entry in html form to .csv file?

Tags: php, html, export-to-csv

I am new and beginner and got some codes from internet by searching and editted according to my needs, but now i want to save the data entry in html form to data.csv file, when i click submit button it should save the contents into data.csv in new line for every click submit button. This html codes i am running local computer only. I don't know how do i that here is MWE. Thanking you in advance for any help

```
 <html>

   <head>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="validate.js"></script>

   </head>

   <body>

   <form action="#" name="StudentRegistration" onSubmit="return(validate());">


 <table cellpadding="2" width="20%" bgcolor="99FFFF" align="center"

   cellspacing="2">

 <tr>

   <td colspan=2>

   <center><font size=4><b>Student Registration Form</b></font></center>

   </td>

   </tr>

 <tr>

   <td>Name</td>

   <td><input type=text name=textnames id="textname" size="30"></td>

   </tr>

 <tr>

   <td>Father Name</td>

   <td><input type="text" name="fathername" id="fathername"

   size="30"></td>

   </tr>

   <tr>

   <td>Postal Address</td>

   <td><input type="text" name="paddress" id="paddress" size="30"></td>

   </tr>

 <tr>

   <td>Personal Address</td>

   <td><input type="text" name="personaladdress"

   id="personaladdress" size="30"></td>

   </tr>

 <tr>

   <td>Sex</td>

   <td><input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" size="10">Male

   <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" size="10">Female</td>

   </tr>

 <tr>

   <td>Stream</td>

   <td><select name="Stream">

   <option value="-1" selected>Select..</option>

   <option value="ARTS">ARTS</option>

   <option value="COMMERCE">COMMERCE</option>

   <option value="SCIENCE">SCIENCE</option>

   </select></td>

   </tr>

 <tr>

   <td>Core-1</td>

   <td><select name="Core-1">

   <option value="-1" selected>Select..</option>

   <option value="English">English</option>

   </select></td>

   </tr>
 <tr>

   <td>Core-2</td>

   <td><select name="Core-2">

   <option value="-1" selected>Select..</option>

   <option value="Alternative English">Alternative English</option>

   </select></td>

   </tr>

 <tr>

 <td>Elective-1</td>

   <td><select name="Elective-1">

   <option value="-1" selected>Select..</option>

   <option value="MIL (Hindi)">MIL (Hindi)</option>
   <option value="MIL (Bengali)">MIL (Bengali)</option>
   <option value="MIL (Nepali)">MIL (Nepali)</option>
   <option value="Political Science">Political Science</option>
   <option value="Education">Education</option>
   <option value="Economics">Economics</option>
   <option value="History">History</option>
   <option value="Geography">Geography</option>
   <option value="Sociology">Sociology</option>
   <option value="Logic & Philosophy">Logic & Philosophy</option>
   <option value="Advance Assamese">Advance Assamese</option>
   <option value="Advance Bengali">Advance Bengali</option>
   <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
   <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
   <option value="Biology">Biology</option>
   <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
   <option value="Computer Science & Applications">Computer Science & Applications</option>
   <option value="Accountancy">Accountancy</option>
   <option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option>
   <option value="Banking">Banking</option>
   <option value="Statistics">Statistics</option>
   </select></td>

   </tr>

   <tr>

   <td>Elective-2</td>

     <td><select name="Elective-2">

   <option value="-1" selected>Select..</option>

   <option value="MIL (Hindi)">MIL (Hindi)</option>
   <option value="MIL (Bengali)">MIL (Bengali)</option>
   <option value="MIL (Nepali)">MIL (Nepali)</option>
   <option value="Political Science">Political Science</option>
   <option value="Education">Education</option>
   <option value="Economics">Economics</option>
   <option value="History">History</option>
   <option value="Geography">Geography</option>
   <option value="Sociology">Sociology</option>
   <option value="Logic & Philosophy">Logic & Philosophy</option>
   <option value="Advance Assamese">Advance Assamese</option>
   <option value="Advance Bengali">Advance Bengali</option>
   <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
   <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
   <option value="Biology">Biology</option>
   <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
   <option value="Computer Science & Applications">Computer Science & Applications</option>
   <option value="Accountancy">Accountancy</option>
   <option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option>
   <option value="Banking">Banking</option>
   <option value="Statistics">Statistics</option>
   </select></td>

   </tr>

   <tr>

   <td>Elective-3</td>

     <td><select name="Elective-3">

   <option value="-1" selected>Select..</option>

   <option value="MIL (Hindi)">MIL (Hindi)</option>
   <option value="MIL (Bengali)">MIL (Bengali)</option>
   <option value="MIL (Nepali)">MIL (Nepali)</option>
   <option value="Political Science">Political Science</option>
   <option value="Education">Education</option>
   <option value="Economics">Economics</option>
   <option value="History">History</option>
   <option value="Geography">Geography</option>
   <option value="Sociology">Sociology</option>
   <option value="Logic & Philosophy">Logic & Philosophy</option>
   <option value="Advance Assamese">Advance Assamese</option>
   <option value="Advance Bengali">Advance Bengali</option>
   <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
   <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
   <option value="Biology">Biology</option>
   <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
   <option value="Computer Science & Applications">Computer Science & Applications</option>
   <option value="Accountancy">Accountancy</option>
   <option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option>
   <option value="Banking">Banking</option>
   <option value="Statistics">Statistics</option>
   </select></td>

   </tr>

   <tr>

   <td>Elective-4</td>

     <td><select name="Elective-4">

   <option value="-1" selected>Select..</option>

   <option value="MIL (Hindi)">MIL (Hindi)</option>
   <option value="MIL (Bengali)">MIL (Bengali)</option>
   <option value="MIL (Nepali)">MIL (Nepali)</option>
   <option value="Political Science">Political Science</option>
   <option value="Education">Education</option>
   <option value="Economics">Economics</option>
   <option value="History">History</option>
   <option value="Geography">Geography</option>
   <option value="Sociology">Sociology</option>
   <option value="Logic & Philosophy">Logic & Philosophy</option>
   <option value="Advance Assamese">Advance Assamese</option>
   <option value="Advance Bengali">Advance Bengali</option>
   <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
   <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
   <option value="Biology">Biology</option>
   <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
   <option value="Computer Science & Applications">Computer Science & Applications</option>
   <option value="Accountancy">Accountancy</option>
   <option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option>
   <option value="Banking">Banking</option>
   <option value="Statistics">Statistics</option>
   </select></td>

   </tr>

   <tr>

   <td>Compulsory</td>

     <td><select name="Compulsory">

     <option value="-1" selected>Select..</option>

       <option value="Environmental Education">Environmental Education</option>

     </select></td>

     </tr>



   <tr>

     <td>Institute</td>

     <td><select name="Institute">

     <option value="-1" selected>Select..</option>

     <option value="Institute-1">Institute-1</option>

     <option value="Institute-2">Institute-2</option>

     <option value="Institute-3">Institute-3</option>

     </select></td>

   </tr>

   <tr>

     <td>State</td>

     <td><select Name="State">

     <option value="-1" selected>select..</option>

     <option value="New Delhi">NEW DELHI</option>

     <option value="Mumbai">MUMBAI</option>

     <option value="Goa">GOA</option>

     <option value="Bihar">BIHAR</option>

     </select></td>

     </tr>

     <tr>

     <td>PinCode</td>

     <td><input type="text" name="pincode" id="pincode" size="30"></td>

   </tr>

     <tr>

     <td>EmailId</td>

     <td><input type="text" name="emailid" id="emailid" size="30"></td>

     </tr>

   <tr>

     <td>DOB</td>

     <td><input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" size="30"></td>

     </tr>

   <tr>

     <td>MobileNo</td>

     <td><input type="text" name="mobileno" id="mobileno" size="30"></td>

     </tr>

     <tr>

     <td><input type="reset"></td>


     <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit Form" /></td>

     </tr>

     </table>

     </form>

     </body>

     </html>
```

Here is the output of the above html codes

[image]

I have created a .php as proces.php file according to Bill suggestion but content not writing but giving only ,,,,,,, here is my php script

```
 <?php
 $fieldA = $_POST["textnames"];
 $fieldB = $_POST["fathername"];
 $fieldC = $_POST["paddress"];
 $fieldD = $_POST["personaladdress"];
 $fieldE = $_POST["sex"];
 $fieldF = $_POST["Stream"];
 $fieldG = $_POST["Core-1"];
 $fieldH = $_POST["Core-2"];
 $fieldI = $_POST["Elective-1"];
 $fieldJ = $_POST["Elective-2"];
 $fieldK = $_POST["Elective-3"];
 $fieldL = $_POST["Elective-4"];
 $fieldM = $_POST["Compulsory"];

 $keys = array($fieldA,$fieldB,$fieldC,$fieldD,$fieldE,$fieldF,$fieldG,$fieldH,$fieldI,$fieldJ,$fieldK,$fieldL,$fieldM); //THIS IS WHERE YOU PUT THE FORM ELEMENTS ex: array('$fieldA','$fieldB',etc)
 $csv_line = array();
 foreach($keys as $key){
     array_push($csv_line,'' . $_GET[$key]);
 }
 $fname = 'data.csv'; //NAME OF THE FILE
 $csv_line = implode(',',$csv_line);
 if(!file_exists($fname)){$csv_line = "\r\n" . $csv_line;}
 $fcon = fopen($fname,'a');
 $fcontent = $csv_line;
 fwrite($fcon,$fcontent);
 fclose($fcon);
 ?>
```

and edited my original html codes from `<form action="#" name="StudentRegistration" onSubmit="return(validate());">` to  `<form name="StudentRegistration" action="proces1.php" method="post">` so here is my new final html coding

```
 <html>

   <head>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="validate.js"></script>

   </head>

   <body>

   <form name="StudentRegistration" action="proces.php" method="post">


 <table cellpadding="2" width="20%" bgcolor="99FFFF" align="center"

   cellspacing="2">

 <tr>

   <td colspan=2>

   <center><font size=4><b>Student Registration Form</b></font></center>

   </td>

   </tr>

 <tr>

   <td>Name</td>

   <td><input type=text name=textnames id="textname" size="30"></td>

   </tr>

 <tr>

   <td>Father Name</td>

   <td><input type="text" name="fathername" id="fathername"

   size="30"></td>

   </tr>

   <tr>

   <td>Postal Address</td>

   <td><input type="text" name="paddress" id="paddress" size="30"></td>

   </tr>

 <tr>

   <td>Personal Address</td>

   <td><input type="text" name="personaladdress"

   id="personaladdress" size="30"></td>

   </tr>

 <tr>

   <td>Sex</td>

   <td><input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" size="10">Male

   <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" size="10">Female</td>

   </tr>

 <tr>

   <td>Stream</td>

   <td><select name="Stream">

   <option value="-1" selected>Select..</option>

   <option value="ARTS">ARTS</option>

   <option value="COMMERCE">COMMERCE</option>

   <option value="SCIENCE">SCIENCE</option>

   </select></td>

   </tr>

 <tr>

   <td>Core-1</td>

   <td><select name="Core-1">

   <option value="-1" selected>Select..</option>

   <option value="English">English</option>

   </select></td>

   </tr>
 <tr>

   <td>Core-2</td>

   <td><select name="Core-2">

   <option value="-1" selected>Select..</option>

   <option value="Alternative English">Alternative English</option>

   </select></td>

   </tr>

 <tr>

 <td>Elective-1</td>

   <td><select name="Elective-1">

   <option value="-1" selected>Select..</option>

   <option value="MIL (Hindi)">MIL (Hindi)</option>
   <option value="MIL (Bengali)">MIL (Bengali)</option>
   <option value="MIL (Nepali)">MIL (Nepali)</option>
   <option value="Political Science">Political Science</option>
   <option value="Education">Education</option>
   <option value="Economics">Economics</option>
   <option value="History">History</option>
   <option value="Geography">Geography</option>
   <option value="Sociology">Sociology</option>
   <option value="Logic & Philosophy">Logic & Philosophy</option>
   <option value="Advance Assamese">Advance Assamese</option>
   <option value="Advance Bengali">Advance Bengali</option>
   <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
   <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
   <option value="Biology">Biology</option>
   <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
   <option value="Computer Science & Applications">Computer Science & Applications</option>
   <option value="Accountancy">Accountancy</option>
   <option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option>
   <option value="Banking">Banking</option>
   <option value="Statistics">Statistics</option>
   </select></td>

   </tr>

   <tr>

   <td>Elective-2</td>

     <td><select name="Elective-2">

   <option value="-1" selected>Select..</option>

   <option value="MIL (Hindi)">MIL (Hindi)</option>
   <option value="MIL (Bengali)">MIL (Bengali)</option>
   <option value="MIL (Nepali)">MIL (Nepali)</option>
   <option value="Political Science">Political Science</option>
   <option value="Education">Education</option>
   <option value="Economics">Economics</option>
   <option value="History">History</option>
   <option value="Geography">Geography</option>
   <option value="Sociology">Sociology</option>
   <option value="Logic & Philosophy">Logic & Philosophy</option>
   <option value="Advance Assamese">Advance Assamese</option>
   <option value="Advance Bengali">Advance Bengali</option>
   <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
   <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
   <option value="Biology">Biology</option>
   <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
   <option value="Computer Science & Applications">Computer Science & Applications</option>
   <option value="Accountancy">Accountancy</option>
   <option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option>
   <option value="Banking">Banking</option>
   <option value="Statistics">Statistics</option>
   </select></td>

   </tr>

   <tr>

   <td>Elective-3</td>

     <td><select name="Elective-3">

   <option value="-1" selected>Select..</option>

   <option value="MIL (Hindi)">MIL (Hindi)</option>
   <option value="MIL (Bengali)">MIL (Bengali)</option>
   <option value="MIL (Nepali)">MIL (Nepali)</option>
   <option value="Political Science">Political Science</option>
   <option value="Education">Education</option>
   <option value="Economics">Economics</option>
   <option value="History">History</option>
   <option value="Geography">Geography</option>
   <option value="Sociology">Sociology</option>
   <option value="Logic & Philosophy">Logic & Philosophy</option>
   <option value="Advance Assamese">Advance Assamese</option>
   <option value="Advance Bengali">Advance Bengali</option>
   <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
   <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
   <option value="Biology">Biology</option>
   <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
   <option value="Computer Science & Applications">Computer Science & Applications</option>
   <option value="Accountancy">Accountancy</option>
   <option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option>
   <option value="Banking">Banking</option>
   <option value="Statistics">Statistics</option>
   </select></td>

   </tr>

   <tr>

   <td>Elective-4</td>

     <td><select name="Elective-4">

   <option value="-1" selected>Select..</option>

   <option value="MIL (Hindi)">MIL (Hindi)</option>
   <option value="MIL (Bengali)">MIL (Bengali)</option>
   <option value="MIL (Nepali)">MIL (Nepali)</option>
   <option value="Political Science">Political Science</option>
   <option value="Education">Education</option>
   <option value="Economics">Economics</option>
   <option value="History">History</option>
   <option value="Geography">Geography</option>
   <option value="Sociology">Sociology</option>
   <option value="Logic & Philosophy">Logic & Philosophy</option>
   <option value="Advance Assamese">Advance Assamese</option>
   <option value="Advance Bengali">Advance Bengali</option>
   <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
   <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
   <option value="Biology">Biology</option>
   <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
   <option value="Computer Science & Applications">Computer Science & Applications</option>
   <option value="Accountancy">Accountancy</option>
   <option value="Business Studies">Business Studies</option>
   <option value="Banking">Banking</option>
   <option value="Statistics">Statistics</option>
   </select></td>

   </tr>

   <tr>

   <td>Compulsory</td>

     <td><select name="Compulsory">

     <option value="-1" selected>Select..</option>

       <option value="Environmental Education">Environmental Education</option>

     </select></td>

     </tr>



   <tr>

     <td>Institute</td>

     <td><select name="Institute">

     <option value="-1" selected>Select..</option>

     <option value="Institute-1">Institute-1</option>

     <option value="Institute-2">Institute-2</option>

     <option value="Institute-3">Institute-3</option>

     </select></td>

   </tr>

   <tr>

     <td>State</td>

     <td><select Name="State">

     <option value="-1" selected>select..</option>

     <option value="New Delhi">NEW DELHI</option>

     <option value="Mumbai">MUMBAI</option>

     <option value="Goa">GOA</option>

     <option value="Bihar">BIHAR</option>

     </select></td>

     </tr>

     <tr>

     <td>PinCode</td>

     <td><input type="text" name="pincode" id="pincode" size="30"></td>

   </tr>

     <tr>

     <td>EmailId</td>

     <td><input type="text" name="emailid" id="emailid" size="30"></td>

     </tr>

   <tr>

     <td>DOB</td>

     <td><input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" size="30"></td>

     </tr>

   <tr>

     <td>MobileNo</td>

     <td><input type="text" name="mobileno" id="mobileno" size="30"></td>

     </tr>

     <tr>

     <td><input type="reset"></td>


     <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit Form" /></td>

     </tr>

     </table>

     </form>

     </body>

     </html>
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the validate script.  Is the validate script only used to validate the blue-green form?  The onsubmit should just have a method like: "OnSubmit="validate();".  Action is set to nothing or "#".  This should be the server side link or reference where the form is submitted to the server.  Maybe validate(); when called sets the action somehow if validation passes and all minimum fields or filled out.

Comment: can you provide back-end code for "Submit Form"

Comment: I don't know html coding, just editting only @Kandy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone Now I finally got the output after editing the proces.php script by changing the line from `$csv_line = array();` to `$csv_line = $keys;` and from `if(!file_exists($fname)){$csv_line = "\r\n" . $csv_line;}` to `if(!file_exists($fname)){$csv_line = $csv_line."\r\n" ;}` here is my final .php file

```
 <?php
 $fieldA = $_POST["textnames"];
 $fieldB = $_POST["fathername"];
 $fieldC = $_POST["paddress"];
 $fieldD = $_POST["personaladdress"];
 $fieldE = $_POST["sex"];
 $fieldF = $_POST["Stream"];
 $fieldG = $_POST["Core-1"];
 $fieldH = $_POST["Core-2"];
 $fieldI = $_POST["Elective-1"];
 $fieldJ = $_POST["Elective-2"];
 $fieldK = $_POST["Elective-3"];
 $fieldL = $_POST["Elective-4"];
 $fieldM = $_POST["Compulsory"];

 $keys = array($fieldA,$fieldB,$fieldC,$fieldD,$fieldE,$fieldF,$fieldG,$fieldH,$fieldI,$fieldJ,$fieldK,$fieldL,$fieldM); //THIS IS WHERE YOU PUT THE FORM ELEMENTS ex: array('$fieldA','$fieldB',etc)
 $csv_line = $keys;
 foreach( $keys as $key ){
     array_push($csv_line,'' . $_GET[$key]);

 }
 $fname = 'data.csv'; //NAME OF THE FILE
 $csv_line = implode(',',$csv_line);
 if(!file_exists($fname)){$csv_line = $csv_line."\r\n" ;}
 $fcon = fopen($fname,'a');
 $fcontent = $csv_line;
 fwrite($fcon,$csv_line);
 fclose($fcon);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This post should get you where you need to go...

[How to export html form to csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264375/how-to-export-html-form-to-csv-file)

The answer there gives a good explanation on how the script works.

edit:
You're going to need to create a PHP file and pass the data when you hit submit FORM should look like this notice the POST and .php file.

```
<form action="NAMEOFFILE.php" method="post">
```

NAMEOFFILE.PHP will contain the form data and the export to CSV script in the link attached. If are not sure how to pass the data this is a straightforward explanation. https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-get-and-post.php

```
<?php
$fieldA = $_POST["textnames"];
$keys = array('id_number','first_name'); //THIS IS WHERE YOU PUT THE FORM ELEMENTS ex: array('$fieldA','$fieldB',etc)
$csv_line = array();
foreach($keys as $key){
    array_push($csv_line,'' . $_GET[$key]);
}
$fname = 'file_to_write_to.csv'; //NAME OF THE FILE
$csv_line = implode(',',$csv_line);
if(!file_exists($fname)){$csv_line = "\r\n" . $csv_line;}
$fcon = fopen($fname,'a');
$fcontent = $csv_line;
fwrite($fcon,$csv_line);
fclose($fcon);
?>
```

The file will be saved on your server with the name "file_to_write_to.csv"

Comment: I gone through the websites you have provided but i donot get any idea@Billy

Comment: I edited my comment with a more in depth explanation of how the script provided works with your form.

Comment: where should i put this line `<form action="NAMEOFFILE.php" method="post">` in my above code? @Billy