# Exporting a HTML form to a CSV file

Tags: php, html, export-to-csv

I have borrowed some code from [an older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48259204/how-to-export-data-entry-in-html-form-to-csv-file) to try and achieve this, but it is not working as expected. There are two issues. First the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>Test Form</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="xyz_form" action="proces.php" method="post">
    <section class="border-bottom">
        <div class="content">
            <h3>ID Number</h3>
            <div class="form-control-group">
                <div class="form-control form-control-number">
                    <input type="number" name="id_number" id="id_number">
                </div>
            </div>
                    <h3>First Name</h3>
            <div class="form-control-group">
                <div class="form-control form-control-text">
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--.content-->
    <section class="data-capture-buttons one-buttons">
       <div class="content">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
       </div>
    </section><!--.data-capture-buttons-->
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

and the PHP code:

```
<?php
$fieldA = $_POST['id_number'];
$fieldB = $_POST['first_name'];

$keys = array($fieldA,$fieldB);
$csv_line = $keys;
foreach( $keys as $key ){
    array_push($csv_line,'' . $_GET[$key]);
}
$fname = 'file_to_write_to.csv';
$csv_line = implode(',',$csv_line);
if(!file_exists($fname)){$csv_line = '\r\n' . $csv_line;}
$fcon = fopen($fname,'a');
$fcontent = $csv_line;
fwrite($fcon,$csv_line);
fclose($fcon);
?>
```

The form runs and does write to the CSV file, but at runtime it throws two warnings:

```
Warning: Undefined array key 3 in E:\XAMPP\App\xampp\htdocs\test_form\proces.php on line 8

Warning: Undefined array key "Third" in E:\XAMPP\App\xampp\htdocs\test_form\proces.php on line 8
```

(3 and "Third" are the two values intered in the form.)

Now it writes to the CSV but the format is incorrect.

```
1,First,,2,Second,,3,Third,,
```

It is adding an extra comma after the two values and not recognising the \r\n for the new lines.

I have tried things ike changing the quotes from single to double. I have also tested changing line 6 `$csv_line = $keys;` to `$csv_line = array();` as suggested in the original post, but that does not fix the problem.

Can some kind person help me sort this out? Thanks.

Comment: Simplify your life and reduce the chances of silly problems by using [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) for writing CSV data in PHP, rather than doing it by hand.

Comment: `action="proces.php"` doesn't contain any parameters, so trying to access anything from `$_GET` isn't ever going to work - which is what the warning messages are telling you.

Comment: Frankly the code in the question you linked to doesn't make much sense. It's unclear where any GET variables are supposed to come from in that script. And in your case it's unclear why you think you need them. Surely you just want to write the ID and name directly into the CSV file from the $_POST array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ADyson clue was the hint to use `fputcsv`. I need the extra parameter eol: to change the default end of line from `\n` to `\r\n`

Here's my PHP now.

```
<?php
$fieldA = $_POST["id_number"];
$fieldB = $_POST["first_name"];

$keys = array($fieldA, $fieldB);
$file_pointer = fopen("file_to_write_to.csv","a");
fputcsv($file_pointer, $keys, eol: "\r\n");
fclose($file_pointer);
?>
```

Comment: Is this an answer that solves the problem? If so, you need to provide an explanation. Code only answers are discouraged. [answer]