# jQuery append HTML form data in CSV file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv

I have simple form like this

```js
function onSubmit( form ){
  var data = JSON.stringify( $(form).serializeArray() );

  console.log( data );
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit='return onSubmit(this)'>
   <fieldset>
    <legend>Dodaj nową wymianę:</legend>
  <select name="size">
   <option selected="selected" value="1">Wybierz rozmiar</option>
   <option value="1,300">1,300</option>
   <option value="1,372">1,372</option>
   <option value="1,500">1,500</option>
   <option value="1,524">1,524</option>
   <option value="1,600">1,600</option>
   <option value="1,700">1,700</option>
   <option value="1,750">1,750</option>
   <option value="1,800">1,800</option>
   <option value="1,8288">1,8288</option>
   <option value="1,8288 zcięte">1,8288 zcięte</option>
   <option value="1,829">1,829</option>
   <option value="2,000">2,000</option>
   <option value="2,032">2,032</option>
   <option value="2,070">2,070</option>
   <option value="2,100">2,100</option>
   <option value="2,200">2,200</option>
   <option value="2,240">2,240</option>
   <option value="2,250">2,250</option>
   <option value="2,350">2,350</option>
   <option value="2,500">2,500</option>
  </select>
  <input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" placeholder="podaj ilość" />
  <input type="text" name="date" id="date" placeholder="dd-mm-rrrr" />
  <label><input type="radio" name="machine" value="ULM" checked="checked" />ULM</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="machine" value="FRENCO" />Frenco</label>
  <input type="text" name="who" placeholder="podaj inicjały np. DN" />
   </fieldset>
   <input type="submit" value="Dodaj" id="add" name="Add"/>
  </form>
```

And I have existing CSV file "test.csv" in the same folder as my html file with form

how can I add data from form to this file, every submit should be new line in CSV I've tried every solution found on google and stack.

No I can't get PHP server on this computer.

Comment: You need server side code to modify the file. Or wrap your code up in an Electron app if you only need it locally

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export html form to csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264375/how-to-export-html-form-to-csv-file)

Comment: You can't do it without any Server Side Languages.