# Download HTML file on anchor tag click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to Download an HTML file on click of anchor tag on another html.

Example:
 1. I have index.html page with the anchor tag (Download Link).

1. I have another html file (download.html).
2. Now i want to download (download.html) file on anchor link click.

i tried using the HTML5 download attribute. but its as we know it not support to IE,safari, and opera browsers.

is their anyway to do this using Javascript ??

Comment: Have you tried this ? 
**  <a href="myfile.html" target="_blank">Download</a> **

Comment: Yes, I did it, but its navigating me on new tab with myfile.html

Comment: You'll need a server side script to add the required header to the response.

Comment: is that html file from the same domain ?

Comment: Yes it is on same Domain...

Answer (score 1):

Without some `PHP` coding stuff it is not possible directly to download a Text file with HTML `enter code here`. You have to compress and `ZIP` that file, and than provide the link in `HTML`.

```
<a href="myfile.zip" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

And also if you decide to use that `PHP` stuff, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903436/write-a-text-file-and-force-to-download-with-php) question.

For doing it to JS read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916191/download-data-url-file) question.

Comment: Is their any way to do it using javascript or JQuery ?

Comment: Romo for this i have to use downloadify plugin right ?

Comment: let me know if you will have any troubleshouting

Comment: Romo, can you give me a sample code for it. using JS ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.href` in javascript

```
<a href="#" target="_blank">Download this</a>
```

then js code just prevent the link from redirecting.

```
$('a').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                window.location.href = 'http://practice.com/materialize.rar';
});
```

Answer (score -2):

To download a file by using anchor tag use following method:
 Download

file path is a path were your file is store after uploading..
suppose you create a folder name "File" in your site folder in which you store a file name adc.doc to download this file use

Download