# lose format when force to download text file in php

Tags: php, text, download

I am using below code for force to download text file in php, below code working properly but after download text file it's losing format of text file or not showing in proper format.

```
$file="license_agreement.txt";
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename(`enter code here`$file).'"'); 
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

Can anyone please let me know what mistaken i have done.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11903544/1548301

Comment: Thanks for your comment but i have already tried this one but can't get text file in proper format.