# Is it possible to save a text file in mobile sd card or internal storage using PHP script

Tags: php

i have a website which is resposive and built mainly for mobile use, Now i want to save a text file to mobile either memory, But from what i have tried it directly saves the file in server. is there a way to save it in mobile memory or giving such patch that it can be saved outside the root directry?

```
$handle = fopen($backup_name,'w+');
fwrite($handle,$content);
fclose($handle);
echo 'done';
```

this is what i have checked so far, in pc i can store it any where but i need it to store in certain location of mobile

Comment: You can download that file. Is this what you are looking for??

Comment: yeah! but i have tried to force download which didnt worked so now i'm trying to write that file to a certain location, if there is a way provide the link so i check it

Comment: if I understand it properly, apache symbolic link might be what you are looking for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903436/write-a-text-file-and-force-to-download-with-php

Comment: If you find a solution for your issue please mark bro))

Comment: i dont know whether permission issue or something else its still shows the text without downloading it, by the way i'm running it on 000webhost.com for free

Answer (score 0):

make .htaccess file inside your downloadable content folder and put below code, Then it will download instead of showing the code.

```
AddType application/octect-stream .txt
```

If it is a .txt file you should do like above. You can put any file type by it's extension.