# Can I configure an HTML button to always "save target as" when being clicked?

Tags: html, button, csv, hyperlink

I'm generating CSV files in an application I'm doing.

Right now I'm displaying the finished files as plain HTML links, but I would like to make them buttons.

**Question:**
Is it possible to configure a button so it triggers the "right click & save target as" action, because clicking on the button will try to load the CSV file in the browser.

If not, is there another way to prevent the button target being clicked and maybe display an alert, so the link is not being followed.

Thanks!

Comment: [Yes](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=force+download)

Comment: Are you only using html? Or are you using php, django, rails...?

Comment: I'd prefer something HTML and/or Javascript/Jquery is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you plan to do this without some server help, but you could take a look at this and see if it helps you get somewhere 
http://www.jtricks.com/bits/content_disposition.html

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look. Right now I'm just trying to prevDefault() the button when it's being clicked and alerting the user this is a download only button

Answer (score 2):

You can force download using PHP

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/force-download');
$musicfile=$_GET["musicfile"];
if(file_exists($musicfile))
{
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$musicfile.'"');
readfile($musicfile);
}
?>
```

Comment: If you own the Server, than you can use .htaccess (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3841691/329766)