# Direct downloading link in browser opening file instead of downloading it

Tags: html, iis

I am trying to create a html simple website on IIS that will help downloading files.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="newUpdater.xml" download="newUpdater.xml">Start automatic download!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This is running file. On clicking "Start automatic download!" it is downloading newUpdater.xml in browser. But, If I directly give this download link in browser (below), it is opening the XML file in all browsers(chrome, firefox).

```
http://169.254.68.202/newUpdater.xml
```

Any Idea How to fix this. I think this is possible as

> http://dl.google.com//googletalk//googletalk-setup.exe

this link on browser will start downloading gtlk directly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841578/is-there-a-way-to-force-the-user-to-download-a-file-from-a-href-link-rather-than?rq=1

ur solution i think

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/11725527/2588097