# Force browser to download an image on click of a link using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, download

I would like to start download  of an image on click of a link.

```
<a id="downloadImage" href="imagepath">Click here to download</a>
```

I know we can use download attribute of HTML5 ([Force a browser to save file as after clicking link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353425/force-a-browser-to-save-file-as-after-clicking-link)) but I would not like to use it as it will not be working in older versions of browsers.
I did tried the method here:
[Download File Using Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)
but it opens the image in the iframe .

Can anybody help me to force a browser to download an image onclick of a link using jquery?

Comment: I *think* this can be solved from the server using the Content-Disposition HTTP header. What server-side technology are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to force the user to download a file from a href link rather than to open it in a browser window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841578/is-there-a-way-to-force-the-user-to-download-a-file-from-a-href-link-rather-than)

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I would like to download this using client side scripting only...FYI we are using Asp.Net

Comment: My opinion is the same as the answer from Vadim.

Comment: same for PDF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598658/how-to-force-a-pdf-download-automatically

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know there is no client-side cross-browser solution for this issue (doesn't matter using jQuery or any other UI toolkit). What you need to do in order to trigger browser to download a file is to add some HTTP headers to the server response:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=image.jpg
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/386845/1580941) post may also be helpful for you.

Comment: How can we do this in asp.net?

Comment: @Maninder Official documentation of adding header for asp.net: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524327(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/force-files-to-download-not-open-in-browser/

Answer (score 5):

You can use the **download** attribute, while not fully supported across browsers, you can use 
[modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to support/fallback for unsupported browsers.

For supported browsers, check http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

```
<a href="/path/to/image.jpg" title="ImageName" download="ImageName" >
    <img src="/path/to/image.jpg" alt="ImageName">
</a>
```