# Javascript handling of php readfile octet stream

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

OK, I've had a good read through the "Related Questions" section and I haven't found this answer.

I'm using an ajax request to [force a php download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465573/forcing-to-download-a-file-using-php).  Things are working fine on the PHP end.  Let's say I've got a stream of data called `DATA`.  Now, I want to pop up a "Save as..." dialog.

The browser has received a string of hex values. Now, what do I do with this `DATA` on the client (javascript) side?

This is the PHP code that I'm using, per the link above:

```
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file');
readfile($file);
```

I've tried

- window.open(`DATA`) -> hex stream doesn't exist (of course)
- submitting a form with the action as `DATA` -> same problem

BTW, If I echo the file from PHP then use window.open, it works sometimes. But not for txt files or jpgs etc.

I've seen this working on other sites - how are they doing it?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer I was looking for:

```
window.open("downloadPage.php");
```

...which pops up a box every time.  The problem with the ajax request was that the returned file stream was interpreted as `XMLHttpRequestObj.reponseText`.

The browser apparently interprets this differently and doesn't allow the download.