# How to open the Save as ..dialog on click of the image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the code.

On click of the link , the save as dialog should open

```
<a href="http://www.experts-exchange.com/xp/images/newNavLogo.png" target="_new">
<img src="http://www.experts-exchange.com/xp/images/newNavLogo.png" align="left" alt="" />
</a>
```

How can we achive this using jQuery, or javaScript?

Comment: It's not done on the client side. It's done on the server side with HTTP headers on the target URL.

Comment: PHP, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718962/force-file-download-in-php  or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930490/javascript-handling-of-php-readfile-octet-stream

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about [`jDownload`](http://jdownloadplugin.com/)?

Example usage is shown on the main page.

**Edit:** The link is now down and there are probably now better plugins for this.

Try http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/

Comment: The link is down.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PHP or any other platform you can always use the force download technique.

This might help:

```
<?php 
$file = 'tag_cloud.gif';
if(!file){
  // File doesn't exist, output error
  die('file not found');
}else{
  // Set headers
  header("Cache-Control: public");
  header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
  header("Content-Type: image/gif");
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
  // Read the file from disk
  readfile($file);
}
?>
```

Call the above script as ajax in the click event of image.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it works only with IE but not with Firefox.

```
</head>
<script>

 function saveImageAs (imgOrURL) {
    if (typeof imgOrURL == 'object')
      imgOrURL = imgOrURL.src;
    window.win = open (imgOrURL);
    setTimeout('win.document.execCommand("SaveAs")', 500);
  }
</script>
<body>

  <A HREF="javascript: void 0"
     ONCLICK="saveImageAs(document.anImage); return false"
  >save image</A>
  <IMG NAME="anImage" SRC="../apache_pb2.gif">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Click to save]

---

```
$("#img").click(function() {
 document.execCommand('SaveAs','1','give img location here');
});
```

---

If that doesnt works use this jquery plugins for cross browser function "Cross-browser designMode"

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/designMode

Comment: Maybe that worked in some distant past, but it does not work now and the link is bad, so don't waste your time.

Answer (score -1):

```
function dl(obj){
   window.location = obj.src;
}

<br/>
..........

<br/>

<img src="http://www.experts-exchange.com/xp/images/newNavLogo.png" align="left" alt="" onClick="dl(this);"/>
<br/>
```

newer browsers will stick to the old page if a download redirect is made.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

html:

```
<img src="http://www.experts-exchange.com/xp/images/newNavLogo.png" align="left" alt="" />
```

script:

```
$('img').each(function(){
  $(this).wrap('<a href="'+this.src+'?download=true" target="_blank"/>');
});
```

most important you need to specify this on server side to send file with disposition attachment when ?downlaod=true was added

Comment: That won't trigger the SaveAs dialog, and `_new` is just plain wrong.

Comment: I updated my answer - removed the wrong new and added a note about server response requirement

Comment: I'm curious about the `"most important you need to specify this on server side to send file with disposition attachment when ?downlaod=true was added"` part ;-)

Comment: it depends of the server, in rails you could write it like this ` send_file(path, :disposition=>(params[:download]? :attachment : :inline) )`