# Codeigniter where in and replace Subquery

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, subquery, where-clause

How do I write in codeigniter in active record the following query?

```
SELECT
  time AS date,
  user AS name
FROM b_table
WHERE id IN(SELECT
          a
        FROM a_table
        WHERE group = $group
        AND tag >= '$date1'
        AND tag <= $date2')
```

This is what I come out with but it does not do the job.

```
$this->db->select('a');
$this->db->from('a_table');
$this->db->where('group',$group);
$this->db->where('tag>=',$date1);
$this->db->where('tag<=',$date2);

$subQuery = $this->db->_compile_select();
$this->db->_reset_select();

$this->db->select('time AS date, user AS name');
$this->db->from('b_table');
$this->db->where_in($subQuery);
```

my problem is (a) from select one is record which need to be replace like replace space to be comma or maybe I'm wrong :(,
another I use str_replace but still wrong,

> > sample data
> >      a from select one is 
> >     222,111,444
> >      333,444
> >     
> >        555,666
> >     replace with 222,111,444,333,444,555,666

even I'm new in codeigniter
Appreciate any helps and sorry for my english. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 ->where()
```

support passing any string to it and it will use it in the query.

so the above will be like:

```
 $this->db->select('time AS date,user AS name')->from('b_table');
 $this->db->where_not_in('id', "SELECT a FROM a_table WHERE group = $group AND tag >= '$date1' AND tag <= $date2");
```

hope it will help!

Comment: can I more question :) how to make it become download button to csv. because posible to make view with many data..I'm very new in codeigniter so please can u make code for that :)

Comment: @AhmanHida I think that is totally different question, for more about this refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634592/download-a-csv-file-straight-to-the-users-download-folder

Comment: @ sandip Thank's but for my subquery where in need to replace space, example if I use Manual query, choose date 01-01-2013 and get some row,
  if I copy that and paste it into the where_in in manually I get a space and it should be a comma (this space make my query not working), how to change it?? Thank's

Comment: @AhmanHida I am not getting what you want to say!, please reexplain

Comment: sory for my poor english, my first select (if manual) from 01-01-2013 to 10-01-2013 get index

Comment: @AhmanHida do you want to say that in the sub-query if one of the date i.e $date1 and $date2 is not provided the query is not running, currect me if I am wrong?

Comment: yes like that .my first select (if manual) from 01-01-2013 to 05-01-2013 get index and got :
1,4,5
6
7
>>5 to 6 to 7 need add comma cause may in date 02-01-2013 and 04-01-2013 in empty so will showing like that
but in select two I need 1,4,5,6,7 for WHERE_IN (in manual will show 1,4,5  6  7, have space so will different or not working)? Thank's

Comment: @AhmanHida don't say thanks in every comment,ok so you want to remove 1,4,5 6 7 sapces between 5 6 7 & make it as 5,6,7 right?

Comment: @AhmanHida see the demo http://codepad.org/p8rtaBe8 where I have created a sample array $var(which is is equivalent of output subquery) I made them a comma separated values. So run the subquery separately ans pass the array to str_replace function & then pass value with comma to where_in query

Answer (score 0):

You are using this in a wrong way. There must be a space after tag in where

```
$this->db->where('tag >=',$date1);
$this->db->where('tag <=',$date2);
```