# How to start download of file?

Tags: php, file, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Forcing to download a file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465573/forcing-to-download-a-file-using-php)

So i am selling something, and I want the file download to start when users go to the thanks page.

The location of the file is stored in `$install`, now when user visits`thanks.php`, how do i start the file download automatically?

Thanks.

Comment: perhaps open new window with the location = $install

Comment: @experimentX nope..that wont be a seemless experience.

Comment: mean .. well, are you planning to control download??

Comment: Asked many times already, for instance here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465573/forcing-to-download-a-file-using-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The majority of what you want to do is actually going to be done in Javascript.

You PHP code will serve up the thanks page, and after it is loaded, you will want to direct a hidden iFrame in your page to a page which serves up the file as a download, using the following headers:

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=yourfile.txt");
readfile($pathToFile);
```

Comment: Javascript? Why? What's wrong with `location` and `redirect` headers? And why would he need to use "hidden iframe"?

Comment: @binaryLV Because I imagine he wants people to *see* and *read* thanks.php. If you used a redirect, they would never see the page.

Comment: Why not? Open "thanks.php" page and send "refresh" header (not "redirect", as I wrote before). What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// place this code inside a php file and call it f.e. "download.php"
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/path2file/"; // change the path to fit your websites document structure
$fullPath = $path.$_GET['download_file'];
if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) {
    $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
    switch ($ext) {
        case "pdf":
        header("Content-type: application/pdf"); // add here more headers for diff. extensions
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); // use 'attachment' to force a download
        break;
        default;
            header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
            header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
    }
    header("Content-length: $fsize");
    header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly
    while(!feof($fd)) {
        $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
        echo $buffer;
    }
}
fclose ($fd);
exit;
// example: place this kind of link into the document where the file download is offered:
// <a href="download.php?download_file=some_file.pdf">Download here</a>
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The alternative to a javascript redirect is using a [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) tag in your HTML. It works even when javascript is disabled.

Comment: "refresh" can also be used as HTTP header.