# Help with PHP Code,trying to download files using a unique url

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Forcing to download a file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465573/forcing-to-download-a-file-using-php)

I am currently building a site where it lets users upload and download files, I am following a tutorial, but am changing it, I want this page to show a download link so that the user can download the file. The files are stored in a MYSQL database.

Here is the code,

```
<?php

include ("Design/header.php"); 
require ("connect.php");

$itemid = $_GET['album'];

$file = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM albums WHERE fileid=''");

include ("Design/footer.php");  

?>
```

I just can't think of how to make a download link just for this file and for it to change for each other file on the site.

I will give more detail,

I have it setup so that when the file is uploaded it is given a unique id, and when the file is click on the site it brings the user to "viewfile.php?file=".$row['fileid']."'>" but on the viewfile.php page I want it so that when "Download File" is click that it downloads the correct file.

Also the code is not finished.

Comment: Always properly escape user input or use parametrized queries, otherwise you'll be vulnerable to SQL injection!

Answer (score 0):

The code below is an example of the general workflow for retrieving data from a DB and returning it to a web page.

```
  <?php
    include ("Design/header.php"); 
    $db = new PDO('dblib:host=your_hostname;dbname=your_db;charset=UTF-8', $user, $pass);

    $itemid = $_GET['album'];

    $preparedStatement = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM contact WHERE fieldid :album');
    $preparedStatement ->bindValue(':album', $itemid);
    $preparedStatement->execute();



    while($row = $preparedStatement->fetchAll())
    {
        echo  "<a href='".$row['fileurl']."'>File Link</a> <br>"
    }

    include 'closedb.php';
    ?>
```

Your general workflow is:

1. Get data from user.
2. Ensure data is sanitized.
3. Run query with data on your DB.
4. Return data to the user using HTML.

Some good references for you:

1. [PDO Class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)
2. [Parametrized Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)
3. [Retrieve Data from MySQL DB](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/retrieve-data-from-a-mysql-database.aspx)

Comment: How would I go implementing this into my site?

Comment: Don't forget to escape/encode URLs! If `fileurl` can contain something like `' onclick="return maliciousFunction()" '`, a user may be vulnerable to [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSS).

Comment: I put it into the site and get this error, Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in /home/a8490126/public_html/viewfile.php on line 3

Comment: Run phpinfo on your server to see if you have PDO enabled, if so you may need to add the following to your php.ini file:
extension="pdo.so"
extension="pdo_mysql.so"

Comment: I changed webhost and get this error now, Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in /home/u559071669/public_html/viewfile.php:3 Stack trace: #0 /home/u559071669/public_html/viewfile.php(3): PDO->__construct('dblib:mysql.fre...', NULL, NULL) #1 {main} thrown in /home/u559071669/public_html/viewfile.php on line 3