# How to download doc, docx files with left click jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I set left mouse click to save the doc (docx) document to my computer? At this moment its only opening doc file in a browser, I want to prevent that. How's that can be done?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SaveAsMe() {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent event onclick
        document.execCommand('SaveAs');
    }
</script>

<a href="sites/mydoc.doc" onclick="SaveAsMe()">download doc file</a>
```

The code above is not working - still opening that doc file in a browser...

I can set that on my test.php page:

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word; charset=windows-1251");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$node->field_book[0]['filename'].".doc");
```

but then when I load test.php it always asks me to save that file... How can I make to work that only for links that leading to doc||docx files?

Comment: This must be configured on the server. Doing that depends on which server/language you're using LAMP? IIS/.NET?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forcing to download a file using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465573/forcing-to-download-a-file-using-php)

Comment: @Diodeus not a duplicate, php isn't even mentioned here. .htaccess seems like the solution in this case

Comment: I guess you didn't read the comments. PHP it is!

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your `.htaccess` file in your sites directory:

```
<Files *.doc> ForceType application/octet-stream Header set Content-Disposition attachment </Files>
```

This will force it to download, and you can use a regular `<a href=''>` to link to the file without any JS intervention.

Comment: thanks, how to set multiplier formats? doc, docx for example?

Comment: Just add another of the same line and change `*.doc` to `*.docx` or whatever you need. Unfortunately, the `<Files>` directive doesn't allow multiple files!

Comment: Actually, a correction, replacing `files` with `filesmatch` allows you to do this `<filesMatch "\.(doc|docx)$">`