# PHP force download json

Tags: php, json, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Forcing to download a file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465573/forcing-to-download-a-file-using-php)

If I have a json in a variable, how can I force the download? (The file not exist).

Thanks.

Comment: post example of code you're trying please

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=file.json');
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $json;
```

Comment: @keepyourweb: Yes, and?  Did you try this?  What happened?

Comment: I make an ajax call where I spend a json, and I would force the download with php. Before I don't specified that I do an ajax call because I thought that it changed nothing.

Comment: @keepyourweb: That changes everything.  You can't force a download from an AJAX call.  You need to submit the form normally, or something.  For the file to be downloaded to the client's PC, the browser needs to actually go to the page.

Answer (score 2):

```
$json = json_encode( array( 'test' => 'test' ));

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=jsonFile.json');
header('Content-type: application/json');

echo( $json);
```

Comment: And...? If you have that code in a page, and you visit that page in your browser, you should get a file download prompt to pop up.  Do you mean something else by 'force download'?

Comment: I make an ajax call where I spend a json, and I would force the download with php. Before I don't specified that I do an ajax call because I thought that it changed nothing.