# Flask: how can a client download a created JSON file

Tags: json, flask

I have a JSON string that I am reading from a web form that I would like to create a temporary file out of and allow the file to be downloaded to the local client machine.  In other words my app.route reads the string, writes the string to a file and then sends the file to the client:

```
@app.route('/sendFile', methods=['POST'])
def sendFile():
    content = str(request.form['jsonval'])
    with open('zones.geojson', 'w') as f:
        f.write(content)
    return send_file(f)
```

What's the best way to make this work?

Comment: Why do you need to write to file if it's temporary? Assuming the submit the form, and it hits your route, I think you can just print the json and set the HTTP headers to download the file instead of showing it. I think `Content-Disposition` header?

Comment: Here is an example (although it uses PHP): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545661/php-force-download-json

Comment: Indeed you can, thanks for getting me on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166970/in-python-using-flask-how-can-i-write-out-an-object-for-download) answer all that is needed is to specify the correct Response header:

```
From flask import Response

@app.route('/sendFile', methods=['POST'])
def sendFile():
    content = str(request.form['jsonval'])
    return Response(content, 
            mimetype='application/json',
            headers={'Content-Disposition':'attachment;filename=zones.geojson'})
```