# Flask: Error when trying to send a JSON file for client download

Tags: python, json, download, io, flask

I have a dictionary that maps one key to multiple values and I want to send that dict as a json file for the user to download.

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET','POST'])
def test():

    data=dict()
    foods=['burger','hotdog']
    foods2=['fries','chips']
    data['John']=foods
    data['Ken']=foods2
    nutrition=jsonify(data)
    return Response(nutrition,
                mimetype='application/json',
                headers={'Content-Disposition':'attachment;filename=nutrition.json'})
```

Followed solution to a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455460/flask-how-can-a-client-download-a-created-json-file), however I get an error of:

`TypeError: 'Response' object is not iterable`

I have also tried sending  `data` as a parameter to `Response`, with no avail. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jsonify` creates a `Response` object for you, so you shouldn't pass that into a `Response` constructor.

```
nutrition = jsonify(data)
nutrition.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=nutrition.json'
return nutrition
```