# symfony download a file

Tags: php, http-headers, symfony-1.4, download, attachment

i have a project with symfony 1.4, in an action a export a mysql table to a .csv file and next download it from the server, i'm using Wampserver for local developement, and everything is working ok, but, when i uploaded to the production server, now, if you try to export the data, the .csv file is automatically open in the browser without asking if you want to saved or open it, the code i use after creating the .csv is this

```
$this->setLayout(false);
sfConfig::set('sf_web_debug', false);
$this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
$this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="file.csv"');
$this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Pragma', 'no-cache');
$this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Expires', '0');
readfile(sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir') . "/export/file.csv");
return sfView::NONE;
```

i repeat, in my local server this work ok, the browser give me the options of open or save, now, is this a problem of the code, a setting in the server or anything else??

the file is saved with utf-8 encode, is this the problem??

thanks

Comment: Have you tried with `application/csv` as content type?

Comment: The `Content-Disposition` header was sent correctly to the client? Servers can modify headers before sending the response back.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forcing to download a file using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465573/forcing-to-download-a-file-using-php)

Comment: not a duplicate, similar but this is also symfony specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, i could get it work, what i did was change the content-type as @j0k suggested, and redirect to the file instead of using the `readfile` function

```
$this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/csv');
$this->redirect('/uploads/export/file.csv');
```

now it is working

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it without redirecting is as follows:

```
  $this->getResponse()->clearHttpHeaders();
  $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Description','File Transfer');
  $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/csv');
  $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Content-Disposition','attachment;filename='.$file_name); 
  $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Pragma', '');
  $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader('Cache-Control', '');
  $this->getResponse()->sendHttpHeaders(); 
  $this->renderText($fwrite('php://output',$stuff));
```

Where you save the file or write the file to 'php://output'.