# Download a recently created file

Tags: php, download

I have a function which currently creates a file and stores it in a folder on my server.

I want to continue doing this but I also want it to force to download.

This is the function:

```
// Generates a filename and writes a CSV with a timestamped name
function putAsCSV($data_list,$account_name,$timeframe){
    $date =  date('d-m-Y-h-i-A');
    $filename = $timeframe.'-'.$account_name.'-'.$date;
    $fp = fopen('../exports/'.$filename.'.csv', 'w');
    foreach ($data_list as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

How can I make it download this file as well as storing it?

Do I need to store it in some sort of temporary file?

How can I ensure it doesn't open in the browser and actually downloads?

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php, you just need to set the correct headers (Content-Type and Content-Disposition) and you can force a download

Comment: This will help too http://stackoverflow.com/a/1465591/1301076

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should utilize the native PHP function readfile for sending data down the wire. It'll prevent clogging up the pipe.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: This is better as a comment.