# Export mysql row string data to .text file in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting echo result from mysql row using following code but I need these output to a .text file which will be generated and downloaded (I don’t need echo it). My sql data is simple string like following-

```
Ar2rew3
df3432ss
sddfdsf
sdfsdfsd
sdfsdsd3
sererere
```

I need just a line break in every string nothing else. Please advise me what code I should add with my current code now? I need very simple solution. i want all my echo output in .text file which will be downloaded

```
echo '<form action="" method="post">
  Email:<input type="text" name="emailadrs"><br>
  Worklink:<input type="text" name="worklink"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></form>';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $emailadrs = $_POST['emailadrs'];
 $worklink = $_POST['worklink'];

 $sub_stat=1;
 $qu = mysql_query("SELECT asin FROM working WHERE w_email='$emailadrs' AND w_asin_link='$worklink' AND submission_status='$sub_stat'");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qu)) {
   $asin = $row['asin']."<br>";
   echo $asin;
 }
}
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465573/forcing-to-download-a-file-using-php, replace `<br>` with `\n` and move the `echo` into a conditional.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I won't directly answer your question as I honestly don't believe it will help you in the long run, I will give you some pointers though...

1) Your script is open to an SQL injection attack - if you carry on going this way its highly likely that anybody can export any part of your database with a carefully crafted SQL injection attack. - Read here: http://shishirceh.blogspot.de/2011/06/sql-injection-beginners-tutorial.html if you don't know what SQL injection is.

2) Looking at your code I'd guess that you're pretty new to PHP (we all have to start somewhere right). Coding "vanilla" PHP can be a pain in the ass, luckily people in the PHP community have created "frameworks" that you can work with which take a lot of the risk out of creating PHP applications. I like using Symfony personally and its really easy to get started with it, tuturial: http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html

3) The way you are using MySQL is quite outdated and not compatible with the latest versions of PHP.  Take a look here for a better alternative:  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

4) The way you are programming (Mixing the bits the user sees and the bits that make the website work) will lead you to a whole lot of problems (security, compatibility with other libraries, sanity) Frameworks will take care of this for you and give you a specific place to put these elements. However to really take advantage of PHP and be a "good" programmer you should really learn object orientated programming first - I'd recommend you read through this book: http://www.ycit-he.org/files/Resources/PHP%20Objects,%20Patterns,%20and%20Practice.pdf

5) If you go down the symfony route they ahve a filesytem component for writing to files: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem/introduction.html

6) With Symfony you can easily force a user to download the file once you have generated it

```
// Generate response
$response = new Response();

// Set headers
$response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'private');
$response->headers->set('Content-type', mime_content_type($filename));
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '";');
$response->headers->set('Content-length', filesize($filename));

// Send headers before outputting anything
$response->sendHeaders();

$response->setContent(file_get_contents($filename));
```

Hope this helps,

Mark