# php download file from server don't work

Tags: php

i have this code that work for me on other projects but now instead to download the file is show the file on browser

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM leads";
$result = $dbconn->query($query);

$filename = "leads_shaldor_" . date("Y-m-d H:i");
$filepath = "/var/www/vhosts/as7.co.il/shaldor.as7.co.il/exports/" 
.$filename. ".csv";
    $downpath = "http://shaldor.as7.co.il/exports/" .$filename. ".csv";
    $csvFile = fopen($filepath, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fprintf($csvFile, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        fputcsv($csvFile, 
array($row['id'],$row['name'],$row['phone'],$row['date']));
        print_r($row);
    }
    fclose($csvFile);
    header("Location: " . $downpath);


$result->close();
$sql->close();
```

Comment: why there is "print_r($row);"?

Answer (score 0):

```
$downpath = "http://shaldor.as7.co.il/exports/" .$filename. ".csv";
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($downpath) . "\"")
```

Set the following headers. It should force a download. Your browser is opening it because it knows how to render the file.

Answer (score 0):

refer to this answer:[Forcing to download a file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465573/forcing-to-download-a-file-using-php)

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.csv');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
readfile("/path/to/yourfile.csv");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use This.

To brute force all CSV files on your server to download, add in your .htaccess file:

```
AddType application/octet-stream csv
```

PHP Solution

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.csv');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
readfile("/path/to/yourfile.csv");
```