# header redirection issue

Tags: php, redirect, header, http-redirect

I'm using `header();` to redirect to the file: http://ozonostudio.com/wp-content/uploads/downloads/2012/09/free.psd_.zip

```
header('Location: ' . $row[3]);
```

where `$row[3]` is the value from SQL. This works for all the browsers except for Safari and Opera.

In Opera, it displays the address but doesn't download anything. I'm trying to download files from external URLs. The users add the link to my database with a form.

UPDATE //////////////////

The original URL is: 
http://ozonostudio.com/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=3

Safari & Opera show the file address, but that browsers don't start with the download, so what is wrong?

Comment: The problem is with the file download itself, most likely.  To learn how to force a download, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470846/send-zip-file-to-browser-force-direct-download

Comment: but i can force the download with external files? and not all the files are zip

Comment: Make sure nothing is sent to the browser before or after the `header()` call. It's always best to call `exit;` immediately after a `Location` header

Answer (score -1):

If your database value always return an external download url in that case you should use

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf'); 
OR header('Content-type: application/zip');
```

OR desired file format

Comment: Those headers have nothing to do with a `Location` redirect (302). Any content type headers will be set in the subsequent response

Comment: i just use this:



`$filename = $row[3];

    $file_name = basename($filename);

    header("Content-Type: mime/type");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));

    readfile($filename);
    exit;`


and work fine now, i just need create a way to validate the URL