# force to download zip from server is not working

Tags: php

I have tried to download file from server using below code but it not downloaded. It shows only content in browser[image: In image there was only code, not any file ..so can you please help me]

```
<?php

if(file_exists($zipName))
{

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\'Uttam_Solanki.zip\'');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipName));
    readfile($zipName);
    exit;

}

?>
```

Comment: try adding .zip to the url end

Comment: @Shank: irrelevant. the browser only uses filename extensions in urls to GUESS what the type might be if the content-type header isn't present. most likely OP has "headers already sent"  warnings, and is running with debug output disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to change role in .htaccess

add application/octet-stream zip

Answer (score 1):

your content-type must be `application/zip

here is a similar approach:

[send zip file to browser / force direct download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470846/send-zip-file-to-browser-force-direct-download)

Comment: that just tells the browser it's a zip file. if you want to force a download, you want to use a mime-type that's NOT likely to have a handler on the user's computer, and/or use a content-disposition header.

Comment: I have tried  Content-type:application/zip but not working

Comment: here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470846/send-zip-file-to-browser-force-direct-download . you seriously have issues downvoting what you don't understand

Comment: i have tried above same questions method but i only content in browser like given in link

Comment: can you send the headers you receive from browser?

Comment: @MiadAbrin my header is
Accept 
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language 
en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control 
no-cache
Connection 
keep-alive
Host 

Pragma 
no-cache
Referer 

User-Agent 
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0

Comment: I mean the response headers

Comment: @MiadAbrin  keep-alive
Content-Length 
329673
Content-Type 
text/html
Date 
Tue, 26 Jul 2016 19:44:47 GMT
Keep-Alive 
timeout=30
Server 
Apache/2
X-Powered-By 
PHP/5.5.22

Comment: As you can see your content type is not correct. I think you should debug you code for any notices or warnings and check you apache rules

Answer (score 0):

How are you triggering this script?

If by link, maybe using [download](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) attribute would help?