# Download a file which opens in the browser instead of downloading

Tags: php, javascript, html, jsp, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to force download of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531292/how-to-force-download-of-a-file)

How to download a file that directly opens in the browser by default. 
For ex- In older browsers, if I opened a link of a mp3 song, then it were downloaded; but now-a-days, they start playing in the browser itself. One method is to right-click the link and click save link as and then save the song; but many times, the link provided is a mask to some other link which is actually the song. So what to do in this case?

Comment: Do you have access to the webserver configuration files?

Comment: @nkr - I don't know. I have to download something from some random website. I don't know how to access webserver configuration file. I don't know even what is webserver configuration file. Sorry.

Comment: So your question is not about programming?

Comment: @nkr - It's about programming only. I want to program some method to download the file instead of running it on the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the content disposition to attachment in the header like this:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment');
```

Also to Include a file name you can use :

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=abc.mp3');
```

Or maybe configure apache[if you're on apache] to have this defined for filetypes you want to force download, like

```
<FilesMatch "\.(mp3|mov|pdf)">
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```